# Angular 2: Only one directive per element

Tags: angular

I understand that Angular 2 beta is only allowing one directive per element. What's the best practice to use *ng-for in conjunction with *ng-if for li elements?

I get the following stack-trace when attempting to put both on the same element.

```
Only one template directive per element is allowed: ng-for var post of postService.state.posts; var $index = index and ng-if cannot be used simultaneously in null
```

For example, filtering from a search.. My @view template code that works is

```
<div>
<h2>Deals</h2>
<input type="text" #ref (keyup)/>
Search: {{ ref.value }}
<ul>
<li *ng-for="var post of postService.state.posts; var $index = index" >
  <p *ng-if="post.value == ref.value || ref.value == '' ">
    {{ post.value + ': $' + post.cost }}
    <br>
    <i> {{ post.qty + ' @ ' + post.drugForm }} </i>
    <small>{{ post.created_at }}</small>
  </p>
</li>
```

However, since *ng-if is on the first sub-element of 'li' tag, it obviously renders an empty list element. Anyone know a proper strategy for this scenario?

Comment: its not called directive anymore, now its components. also, they are changing quite a lot the syntax

Comment: There's a lot up-in-the-air for sure and there was a funeral procession for Directives and controllers and factories etc. Nonetheless, the stack trace for this problem still says Directive. I'll add the trace text above..

Answer (score 3):

What you're looking in Angular 1 would be a `filter`, in Angular2 they're `pipes`.

`<li *ng-for="var post of postService.state.posts; var $index = index">`

Will become:

```
<li *ng-for="var post of postService.state.posts; var $index = index |
 filter(post.value == ref.value || ref.value == '')" >
```

That filter doesn't currently exist, but there are hints it will come in a discussion about [pipes in Angular 2](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/1625)

For now, you can use an observable pipe `rx` with `ng-control="query"`.

```
<input type="text" ng-control="query" (keyup)/>
<li *ng-for="var post of postService.state.posts; var $index = index | rx>
```

You'll process the search query with a function.

```
search(query){
    return /* map over posts that match and return only matches */
  }
```

Currently this API isn't nearly as sugared as it will end up being, so it requires **a lot of setup**.

Have a look at [a working example using the YouTube Search API](http://embed.plnkr.co//RxPipe.js).