# Angular2 hide element in ng-for

Tags: angular

How do I filter elements when using ng-for?

```
<tr>
    <td *ng-for="#col of columns" ><a (click)="sort(col.name)">{{col.title}}</a></td>
</tr>
```

I don't want to create a  element when col.visible is false

How do I do this in Angular2?

Comment: I think what you need is what was called in Angular 1 a filter, which is now called a pipe, see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31214924/angular-2-only-one-directive-per-element. check this on pipes https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/pipes/ and how to create a custom one -> https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/change_detection/Pipe-class.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use a pipe to filter the data so that only a subset is used by `*ngFor` like explained in

[How to apply filters to *ngFor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34164413/angular2-how-to-apply-filters-to-ng-for)

or you can use `*ngIf` with `*ngFor`, but they are not allowed on the same element. How to use them together anyway is explained in [*ngIf and *ngFor on same element causing error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34657821/ngif-and-ngfor-on-same-element-causing-error)

Answer (score 0):

Use **ngIf** directive. **col.visible = true** means only the td is added otherwise it won't be added in the tr.

> The ngIf directive removes or recreates a portion of the DOM tree
>   based on an {expression}. If the expression assigned to ngIf evaluates
>   to a false value then the element is removed from the DOM, otherwise a
>   clone of the element is reinserted into the DOM.

```
<tr>
    <td ng-if="col.visible" ng-for="#col of columns" ><a ng-click="sort(col.name)">{{col.title}}</a></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Only one template directive per element is allowed: ng-if col.visible and ng-for cannot be used simultaneously in null

Comment: what is ng-for its a custom directive ah??

Answer (score 0):

In this case the simplest thing to do is to ensure that your columns array is only populated with col objects where `col.visible === true`.

Doing that in the controller class will fix this problem without any markup filters or other framework specific dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Angular2 syntax has changed a bit.  For the release, the syntax for a *ngIf is:

```
<div class="row pre-scrollable" *ngIf="count > 0">
    <div *ngFor="let image of results">
        {{image.title}}
    </div>
</div>
```

The results is an array of some objects that have a title and count is the number of items in that array.

In this case, the div is used to have a scrollable list of results and if there are no results, to hide the scrollbar.