# Search pipe for Angular2

Tags: json, search, angular, pipe

I am working on some project and i can't find the right answer for my search pipe. This is my code:

```
import {Pipe} from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'SearchPipe'
})

export class SearchPipe {


 transform (value, [queryString]) {
    if (value==null) {
      return null;
    }
    if (value=="") {
      return null;
    }

    if(queryString !== undefined){
        return   value.filter(item=>item.model.toLowerCase().indexOf(queryString.toLowerCase()) !== -1)         ;
    }else{
        return value;
    }
  }
}
```

And i get all search result that contain letter A when i enter that in search. I need to search my json with word not with letter. Sorry for my bad language, i hope you will understand it. This is the JSON.

```
[
  {

    "brand": "Suzuki",
    "condition": "polovno",
    "salesman": "Automotive",
    "model": "Vitara"
  }
]
```

If someone can modify code i would be very happy. 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the brackets around the queryString parameter. You can pass that in via a parameterized pipe (e.g. **SearchPipe:queryString**).

Here's a [plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/WQzqGsXJmtQJLiiEbJv3/) example.

Answer (score 1):

I've created a plunker based off of answers [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34164413/how-to-apply-filters-to-ngfor).

Additionally I had to add an `@Input`, `@ViewChild`, and `ElementRef` of the `<input>` and create and `subscribe()` to an observable of it.

Angular2 Search Filter: [PLUNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/WitglQDcZku4ZxHgi5yj?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the filter logic you have but try this out if it woks

```
import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'SearchPipe'
})

export class SearchPipe implements PipeTransform{


 transform (value, [queryString]) {
    if (value==null || value=="") {
      return null;
    }

    if(queryString !== undefined){
        return   value.filter(item=>item.model.toLowerCase().indexOf(queryString.toLowerCase()) !== -1)         ;
    }else{
        return value;
    }
  }
}
```