# Search a value in a nested array of objects angular2

Tags: javascript, object, angular

I have started working on angular2 recently.So want to know the right approach for the use-case. I have an array of Objects like this :

```
users : Array<Object> = [{
    id: 1,
    tags: [{
        name: 'foo',
        age: 21
    }, {
        name: 'aaa',
        age: 23
    }]
}, {
    id: 2,
    tags: [{
        name: 'ball',
        age: 53
    }, {
        name: 'ttt',
        age: 43
    }]
}, {
    id: 3,
    tags: [{
        name: 'bar',
        age: 32
    }, {
        name: 'fsf',
        age: 11
    }]
}]
```

I need to display this data as a table and give a search option on it.
Data needs to be filtered on the basis of the text entered by a user in the search field. The data entered in the search can match any of the values in this object. I am using angular2 rc4.

I need help in implementing this search and the way I should approach it. I am also using lodash. Is there any way I can utilise its functions. 
( without using jquery )

Comment: Just a syntax issue: users: Array<Object>

Comment: @KobiCohen  corrected.

Comment: What does this have to do with angular?

Answer (score 0):

See here [How to apply filters to *ngFor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34164413/how-to-apply-filters-to-ngfor)

Basically to implement a pipe that return whatever you need

Comment: Pipes aren't considered a great idea for most data filtering or sorting scenarios. Check out the section at the end of this page: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html. Example quote: "The Angular team and many experienced Angular developers strongly recommend that you move filtering and sorting logic into the component itself."

Answer (score 0):

In Lodash, you can filter using [`_.filter`](https://lodash.com/docs#filter), [`_.some`](https://lodash.com/docs#some), and [`_.includes`](https://lodash.com/docs#includes):

```js
var users = [{"id":1,"tags":[{"name":"foo","age":21},{"name":"aaa","age":23}]},{"id":2,"tags":[{"name":"ball","age":53},{"name":"ttt","age":43}]},{"id":3,"tags":[{"name":"bar","age":32},{"name":"fsf","age":11}]}];

var searchItem = "foo";

var filtered = _.filter(users, user =>
                 _.some(user.tags, tag =>
                   _.includes(tag, searchItem)));

console.log(filtered);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.15.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

If you want to find substring matches also, map the fields to a string and then use [`String#indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf):

```js
var users = [{"id":1,"tags":[{"name":"foo","age":21},{"name":"aaa","age":23}]},{"id":2,"tags":[{"name":"ball","age":53},{"name":"ttt","age":43}]},{"id":3,"tags":[{"name":"bar","age":32},{"name":"fsf","age":11}]}];

var searchItem = "f";

var filtered = _.filter(users, user =>
                 _.some(user.tags, tag =>
                   _.some(tag, field =>
                     _.toString(field).indexOf(searchItem) != -1)));

console.log(filtered);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.15.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's how you'd filter in HTML, or do you want to filter in the controller?

```
 <li ng-repeat="user in users | filter: { tags: [{ age: search.age}] }">
```

I found a plunkr of someone else doing something similar:

http://jsfiddle.net/suCWn/12/

Controller:

```
$scope.filteredUsers = $filter('filter')(users, function(value) {

    return angular.forEach(value.tags, function(tag) {

      return tag === $scope.searchTerm;

    });
  });
```

Comment: I think he ask for angular2 rc4 solution

Comment: Ahhh sorry yea missed that part. They didn't do away with filter in Angular 2 though did they?

Comment: I want to search in controller.  And it is just like a search option you have at the top of a table. Whatever string you write in the search, table displays only the results matching the string entered.

Comment: @cullimorer, i am using angularr2 rc4 and moreover that solution is good when i have to search based on a known key. But in this case i don't know value could be for any key. 
For example :  If i write 1, it should return the object with id 1.  If i write 'ball' then it should return the parent object with name  as ball.