# Angular 2 Tour of Heroes: Filter heroes by name

Tags: angular, web, typescript

I have followed the Angular 2 tour of Heroes tutorial, and I am currently at this stage:

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt6.html

I can search in the search bar, and a list of hero name suggestions come up

Plunker: https://angular.io/resources/live-examples/toh-6/ts/eplnkr.html

However, what I want, is a filter bar, where I search, and the hero block automatically gets filtered depending on what is in the filter bar.

For example, in the link I provided, if I type in "Bo" in the search bar, I only want the hero block "Bombasto" to show up on the screen. When I clear the search bar, all the blocks should reappear. Does someone know how to do this?

Comment: Maybe you could create a minimal plunker?

Comment: Theres a plunker in the link I provided (towards the bottom).

Comment: I should really have added it to the post. Here you go https://angular.io/resources/live-examples/toh-6/ts/eplnkr.html

Comment: this might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34165371/5115768  basically you create a `custom pipe` which filters your `heroes` array based on the search string (in the answer called `filterargs`)

Comment: So you want the hero's displayed in the dashboard component to change based on what's in the search box?

Comment: @Peza Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at my modified plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/YHzyzm6ZXt4ESr76mNuB?p=preview

1. Added a `Pipe` to the dashboard.component.ts

```js
@Pipe({
  name: 'filterHeros'
})
export class FilterHeroPipe {
  public transform(heros: Hero[], filter: string) {
    if (!heros || !heros.length) return [];
    if (!filter) return heros;
    return heros.filter(h => h.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(filter.toLowerCase()) >= 0);
  }
}
```

2. Use this `Pipe` inside of that dashboard.template

```html
<h3>Top Heroes</h3>
<div class="grid grid-pad">
  <a *ngFor="let hero of (heroes | filterHeros : heroSearch.curSearch )"  [routerLink]="['/detail', hero.id]"  class="col-1-4">
    <div class="module hero">
      <h4>{{hero.name}}</h4>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
<br />
<hero-search #heroSearch></hero-search>
```

3. Change that `HeroSearch` component:

```js
  private searchTerms = new Subject<string>();
  public curSearch: string; // !! NEW !!

  constructor(
    private heroSearchService: HeroSearchService,
    private router: Router) {}

  // Push a search term into the observable stream.
  search(term: string): void {
    this.curSearch = term;  // !! NEW !!
    this.searchTerms.next(term);
  }
```

4. don't forget to add our `Pipe` to our app.module:

```js
import { DashboardComponent, FilterHeroPipe }   from './dashboard.component';
import { HeroesComponent }      from './heroes.component';
import { HeroDetailComponent }  from './hero-detail.component';
import { HeroService }          from './hero.service';
import { HeroSearchComponent }  from './hero-search.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    InMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(InMemoryDataService),
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    DashboardComponent,
    HeroDetailComponent,
    HeroesComponent,
    HeroSearchComponent,
    FilterHeroPipe
  ],
  providers: [ HeroService ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```