# I have a officeLocations Array and I want to display it in html with the help of isOpened property in angular

Tags: angular, angular5

I have an array named officeLocationsArray in officeLocation.ts file as follows.

```
export class OfficeLocation
{
    officeLocationName:string;
    Isopened:boolean;
}
export const officeLocationArray : OfficeLocation[] = [
    {officeLocationName : 'India' , Isopened:false },
    {officeLocationName : 'UK' , Isopened:false },
    {officeLocationName : 'USA' , Isopened:false }
];
```

Now in my html I am doing an iteration of this officeLocationArray

```
  <select class="form-control" name="officeLocation" id="officeLocation" formControlName="officeLocation">
                                                <option *ngFor="let countryName of officeLocations" value="{{countryName.officeLocationName}}">{{countryName.officeLocationName}}</option>
                                        </select>
```

Now I wanted to display the officeLocationNames based on the IsOpened property. When I apply ngIf it is popping an error that ngIf and ngFor cant be applied to single element in html .

Comment: You can write a pipe. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34164413/how-to-apply-filters-to-ngfor or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44888331/how-to-filter-items-inside-ngfor-loop-in-angular-4-using-input-field

Comment: Thank You Stephan M

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the array for just opened offices and iterate over it.

```
export const openedOfficeLocations: OfficeLocation[] = officeLocationArray.filter((office) => office.Isopened);
```

Comment: Thank You Fernando Fairas. It helped.