# Select tag show only active values

Tags: angular

Hi I am having below array where I need to show only codes in dropdown where status:active I tried using ngif in options tag like `*ngIf="c.status=='Active'"` but not working how to show only active objects.

```
<select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="addproduct.code">
     <option *ngFor="let c of allProducts"  [value]="c.code" id="{{c.code}}">{{ c.code }}</option>
</select>
```

In component :

```
  getAllProducts(){
      this.superuserViewAccountpreferencessService.getProductDetails().subscribe(
        res => {
          this.allProducts = res['products'];
        }
      )
    }
```

i will get response as:

```
[{
    "code": "PLATINUM",
    "status": "Active",
    "cost": 100
}, {
    "code": "PlatinumTe",
    "cost": 123
}, {
    "code": "Test11",
    "cost": 1234
}, {
    "code": "PLATINUM22",
    "status": "Active",
    "cost": 1000
}]
```

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34164413/how-to-apply-filters-to-ngfor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just filter out the items that have `status === 'Active'` before you store them in your property

```
this.allProducts = res['products'].filter(item => item.status === 'Active');
```