# How to get filtered list array of ngfor data in angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a data array which contains many objects (JSON format). The following can be assumed as the contents of this array:

```
var data = [
  {
    "name": "Jim",
    "age" : 25
  },
  {
    "name": "Jerry",
    "age": 27
  }
];
```

Now, I display these details as:

```
<div ng-repeat="person in filtered = (data | filter: query)">
</div>
```

Here i will be able to get the filtered list based on the query string.

How can i achieve the same in angular2 "ngfor"?

Comment: <div *ngFor="let person of data | yourFilterPipe: filter-args">

Comment: What type of data do you want to filter?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to apply filters to \*ngFor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34164413/how-to-apply-filters-to-ngfor)

Answer (score -3):

your best bet is to populate the filtered values into a new array your `*ngFor` call will use.

This is the most sensible, and easiest solution that I have found, as well you can also filter on the database.