# Restrict the display of a table on angular 4

Tags: angular, angular4-forms

please can someone help me to control the display of my table?
I explain myself... here is my code:

```
    <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-hover" id="customers">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Client N°</th>
                        <th>Nom</th>
                        <th>Prénom</th>
                        <th>Adresse</th>
                        <th>Date de Naissance</th>
                        <th>Téléphone</th>
                        <th>Ajoute Par</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr *ngFor="let c of clients" class="table-active" style="cursor: pointer;">
                        <td>{{c.id}}</td>
                        <td>{{c.nom}}</td>
                        <td>{{c.prenom}}</td>
                        <td>{{c.adresse}}</td>
                        <td>{{c.date_naissance}}</td>
                        <td>{{c.portable}}</td>
                        <td>{{c.user_id}}</td>
...
```

this code allows me to display all my clients from the database. But i want to display now every clients whose **user_id** equals **1** for example.

Hoping i have made myself clear, can someone please tell if it is possible in **angular 4 HTML**? if it is, please can you tell me how? i think i'm gonna use like **NgIf** but i'm not sure.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to apply filters to \*ngFor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34164413/how-to-apply-filters-to-ngfor)

Comment: thanks @CornelC i wil check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**in HTML**

```
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let c of filteredClients" class="table-active" style="cursor: pointer;">

...
```

**in TS**

```
filteredClients: any[];
clients: any[];

getClients() {
    this.service.getCLients().subscribe(res => {
        this.clients = res;
        this.filteredClients = clients.filter(client => client.id == 1);    
        // this could be used for further filtering, suppose you have an input to filter other things as well.
    });
}
```

You can also use *ngIf as you mentioned but better to control data from TS.

Comment: @BaNRoOt glad to hear that :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
     <tbody>
        <ng-template *ngFor="let c of clients">
            <tr class="table-active" style="cursor: pointer;" *ngIf="c.user_id==1">
                <td>{{c.id}}</td>
                <td>{{c.nom}}</td>
                <td>{{c.prenom}}</td>
                <td>{{c.adresse}}</td>
                <td>{{c.date_naissance}}</td>
                <td>{{c.portable}}</td>
                <td>{{c.user_id}}</td>
            </tr>
        </ng-template>
    </tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey I think you can simplify your code using ng-repeat

```
<tr  ng-repeat="c in clients|filter:{c.id:1}" class="table-active" style="cursor: pointer;">
                        <td>{{c.id}}</td>
                        <td>{{c.nom}}</td>
                        <td>{{c.prenom}}</td>
                        <td>{{c.adresse}}</td>
                        <td>{{c.date_naissance}}</td>
                        <td>{{c.portable}}</td>
                        <td>{{c.user_id}}</td>
</tr
```