# Angular - How to filter ngFor to specific object property data

Tags: angular

I have this data in in-memory-data.service.ts:

```
import {InMemoryDbService} from 'angular-in-memory-web-api';
export class InMemoryDataService implements InMemoryDbService {
createDb() {
const values = [
  {
    id: 0,
    title: 'Calculus',
    author: 'John Doe',
    date: '2018-05-15',
    content: 'Random text',
    category: 'Science'
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    title: 'Bulbasaur',
    author: 'John Doe',
    date: '2000-09-14',
    content: 'Random text',
    category: 'TV shows'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: 'Fourier Analysis',
    author: 'John Doe',
    date: '2014-01-01',
    content: 'Random text',
    category: 'Science'
  }
];

return {values};
  }
}
```

Currently I am displaying the data in one of my components:

```
<ol class="list-unstyled mb-0">
  <li *ngFor="let value of values">{{value.title}}</li>
</ol>
```

How can I display only category "Science" values?

Answer (score 9):

You can filter it out using `filter` of java script which return new array containing your required data , like this :

```
this.filteredvalues = values.filter(t=>t.category ==='Science');
```

and then you can iterate over this filtered array

```
<li *ngFor="let value of filteredvalues ">{{value.title}}</li>
```

Comment: anything different from my answer?

Comment: @Sajeetharan, Yes you Bind `filteredvalues` to local scope using `let` which is not accessible to view/template part. Anyways we wrote answer at the same time using same method

Comment: ok got it! but that was just a sample! thanks for the feedback

Comment: yup, I Know, Already told you It was just an coincidence the we posted almost slimier concept for the answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use **[array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)** to filter the matching values

```js
const values = [
  {
    id: 0,
    title: 'Calculus',
    author: 'John Doe',
    date: '2018-05-15',
    content: 'Random text',
    category: 'Science'
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    title: 'Bulbasaur',
    author: 'John Doe',
    date: '2000-09-14',
    content: 'Random text',
    category: 'TV shows'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: 'Fourier Analysis',
    author: 'John Doe',
    date: '2014-01-01',
    content: 'Random text',
    category: 'Science'
  }
];

let filteredvalues = values.filter(t=>t.category ==='Science');
console.log(filteredvalues);
```

So the matching HTML would be,

```
<ol class="list-unstyled mb-0">
  <li *ngFor="let value of filteredvalues ">{{value.title}}</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also have the filter logic isolated if you want it to be reusable.
You can create a custom pipe using the filter condition you want.
and then use the pipe in template as

```
<li *ngFor="let value of values | customFilter:filtercond">
```

and you can define the filtercond in your component as per your requirement

```
filtercond = {category: 'Science'};
```

similar issue is addressed here: [apply filters to *ngFor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34164413/how-to-apply-filters-to-ngfor)