# Organize categories of products Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm trying to make this code work on an Angular project, in vanilla JS works fine but I'm having trouble with the for loop in Typescript, for now in my Angular view I just print the list of products with *ngFor but I need to separate by categories. I'm looking to replace the for loops with arrays methods like `map()` or `filter()` but I can't figure out how to do that. How can I achieve this with Angular *ngFor?

```js
var products = [
        {id: 1, name: 'Apple', category: 'Fruit'},
        {id: 2, name: 'Orange', category: 'Fruit'},
        {id: 3, name: 'Blueberry', category: 'Jam'},
        {id: 4, name: 'Sugar', category: 'Sweet'},
        {id: 5, name: 'Candy', category: 'Sweet'},
        {id: 6, name: 'Cheese', category: 'Cheese'}
];

    
//get categories
let categories = [];
for (let i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
    if(!categories.includes(products[i].category)){
        categories.push(products[i].category);
    }
}
console.log(categories);


//get products by category
for(item of categories){
    console.log(item);
    let filtered = products.filter(x => x.category == item);
    console.log(filtered);
}

/*
Expected output

Fruit
{id: 1, name: 'Apple', category: 'Fruit'},
{id: 2, name: 'Orange', category: 'Fruit'},

Jam
{id: 3, name: 'Blueberry', category: 'Jam'},

Sweet
{id: 4, name: 'Sugar', category: 'Sweet'},
{id: 5, name: 'Candy', category: 'Sweet'},

Cheese
{id: 6, name: 'Cheese', category: 'Cheese'}
*/
```

Angular view:

```js
<div>
    <div *ngFor="let product of products">
         <div class="card-body">
             <p>{{product.name}}</p>
             <p>{{product.category}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe something like https://stackoverflow.com/a/50591974/1918727

Comment: Not exactly Juan, thanks

Comment: "filtered" doesn't contain already what you need?

Comment: in vanilla JS works fine, im having trouble with typescript, im just looking a way to organize this with array methods instead for loops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To display your data, you could rework your data in a more ngFor-friendly shape. Here is [a repro on Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-m1zhd4?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) and here is the code :

ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  name = "Angular";
  products = [
    { id: 1, name: "Apple", category: "Fruit" },
    { id: 2, name: "Orange", category: "Fruit" },
    { id: 3, name: "Blueberry", category: "Jam" },
    { id: 4, name: "Sugar", category: "Sweet" },
    { id: 5, name: "Candy", category: "Sweet" },
    { id: 6, name: "Cheese", category: "Cheese" }
  ];

  arrangedProducts = {};

  ngOnInit() {
    this.products.forEach(p => {
      if (!this.arrangedProducts || !this.arrangedProducts[p.category]) {
        this.arrangedProducts[p.category] = [p];
      } else {
        this.arrangedProducts[p.category].push(p);
      }
    });


    // if Object.values throw an error (Not working with ES2017 ?), use Object.keys().map() :
    // https://stackoverflow.com/a/42966443/9868549 and the next answer
    // this.arrangedProducts = Object.values(this.arrangedProducts);
    
    this.arrangedProducts = Object.keys(this.arrangedProducts).map(
      key => this.arrangedProducts[key]
    );
    console.log(this.arrangedProducts);
  }
}
```

html:

```
<div *ngFor="let arrayOfProducts of arrangedProducts; let i = index">
    <h2>{{arrayOfProducts[0].category}}</h2>
    <div *ngFor="let product of arrangedProducts[i]">
        {{product.name}}
    </div>
</div>
```

[Edit]: I added a change for `Object.values` which throw an error in Stackblitz, just in case it bother you.

---

You could also simply sort your array of data and display it as in [this other repro on Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4nfifl?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts), here is the code :

ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  name = "Angular";
  products = [
    { id: 1, name: "Apple", category: "Fruit" },
    { id: 6, name: "Cheese", category: "Cheese" },
    { id: 2, name: "Orange", category: "Fruit" },
    { id: 4, name: "Sugar", category: "Sweet" },
    { id: 3, name: "Blueberry", category: "Jam" },
    { id: 5, name: "Candy", category: "Sweet" },
  ];

  arrangedProducts = [];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.arrangedProducts = this.products.sort(this.compare);
    console.log(this.arrangedProducts)
  }

  compare(a, b) {
    if (a.category < b.category) {
      return -1;
    }
    if (a.category > b.category) {
      return 1;
    }
    return 0;
  }

  getPreviousCategory(i){
    if(i-1 < 0) return;
    return this.arrangedProducts[i-1].category;
  }
}
```

html:

```
<div *ngFor="let product of arrangedProducts; let i = index">
    <h2 *ngIf="getPreviousCategory(i) !== product.category">{{product.category}}</h2>
  {{product.name}}
</div>
```

This second method allow you to directly sort your array as you wish (adc or desc, depending on what your put in the compare method).

Comment: @sonEtLumiere You're welcome :) If this is the answer you wanted, you can tag it as the accepted answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could derive your unique set of categories like this in your component:

```
this.categories = [...new Set(this.products.map(item => item.category))];
```

(thanks @Vlad Bezden to https://stackoverflow.com/a/35092559/442665)

Then your view would conditionally display them based on the categories:

```
<div *ngIf="product.category === category">
```

Here's an example:

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  products = [
    {id: 1, name: 'Apple', category: 'Fruit'},
    {id: 2, name: 'Orange', category: 'Fruit'},
    {id: 3, name: 'Blueberry', category: 'Jam'},
    {id: 4, name: 'Sugar', category: 'Sweet'},
    {id: 5, name: 'Candy', category: 'Sweet'},
    {id: 6, name: 'Cheese', category: 'Cheese'}
  ];
  categories;

  constructor() {
    this.categories = [...new Set(this.products.map(item => item.category))];
    console.log(this.categories);
  }
}
```

Here's the view:

```
<div>
  <div *ngFor="let category of categories; index as i;">
    <div class="header">{{category}}</div>
    <div *ngFor="let product of products; index as i;">
      <div *ngIf="product.category === category">
      {{product.name}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.header {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Here's the example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-kalam-du9n7?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Answer (score 1):

I solved this type of problem in my Angular app in this way like below:

In **CategoryProductsComponent.ts** file,

```
  @Input() products: IProduct[];
  categorizedProducts = {};

  constructor(private router: Router, private cartService: CartService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.products.forEach((p) => {
      if (!this.categorizedProducts || !this.categorizedProducts[p.category]) {
        this.categorizedProducts[p.category] = [p];
      } else {
        this.categorizedProducts[p.category].push(p);
      }
    });

    this.categorizedProducts = Object.keys(this.categorizedProducts).map(
      (key) => this.categorizedProducts[key]
    );
    console.log(this.categorizedProducts);
  }
```

In **CategoryProdcutsComponent.html** file,

```
    <!-- container -->
        <div class="container">
          <!-- row -->
          <div class="row" *ngFor="let arrayOfProducts of categorizedProducts; let i = index">
    
    
            <!-- section title -->
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <div class="section-title">
                <h2 class="title category-title"> {{arrayOfProducts[0].category}} </h2>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /section title -->
      
            <!-- Products tab & slick -->
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="card-deck">
                  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6" *ngFor="let product of categorizedProducts[i]">
                    <div class="card my-2">
                      <img
                        [src]="product.image"
                        alt="{{ product.title }}"
                        width="200px"
                        height="300px"
                        class="card-img-top"
                        style="cursor: pointer"
                        (click)="selectProduct(product._id)"
                      />
                      <div class="card-header">
                        <div class="card-title">
                          <p>{{ product.title.substr(0, 50) | uppercase }}</p>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="card-body">
                        <h6>{{ product.description.substr(0, 150) }} ...</h6>
                        <h3 class="">{{ product.price | currency: "USD" }}</h3>
                        <p>
                          <del class="product-old-price">{{
                            product.price + product.price * 0.1 | currency: "USD"
                          }}</del>
                          (10% Off)
                        </p>
                      </div>
      
                      <div
                        class="row d-flex justify-content-center border-primary my-3"
                      >
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                          <button
                            class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm btn-block"
                            [class.disabled]="product.quantity < 1"
                            [class.btn-outline-danger]="product.quantity < 1"
                            (click)="
                              product?.quantity <= 0
                                ? notifyEmpty(product?.title)
                                : addToCart(product?._id)
                            "
                          >
                            {{ product.quantity < 1 ? "NO STOCK" : "Add To Cart" }}
                          </button>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Products tab & slick -->
          </div>
         <!-- /row -->
      </div>
  <!-- /container -->
```