# Filter by specific JSON value to binding Angular 5

Tags: json, angular, binding

I have a JSON object with this aspect:

[json structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0IPh.jpg)

I would like to be able to perform a binding for the key value, that is, to be able to do array.company (and to show the content of value for example: "Anonymous 3 Company S.A"). Is this possible? I have only managed to print the whole object at once:

```
<div *ngFor="let sa of serverAttributes">
    {{ sa.key}}
    {{sa.value}}
</div>
```

This is my .ts file:

```
this.subscriptions = this.cbank.getAssetServerAttributes(this.localCustomer, data[indexx]).subscribe(vres => {
    this.serverAttributes.push(vres[indexx]);
    indexx++;
});
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34164413/how-to-apply-filters-to-ngfor

Comment: In my case, what should I put in the variables filterargs and items?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34164413/how-to-apply-filters-to-ngfor

Answer (score 0):

```
create a custom pipe to return the list of key and value You could also return an entry containing both key and value:

@Pipe({name: 'keys'})
export class KeysPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value, args:string[]) : any {
    let keys = [];
    for (let key in value) {
      keys.push({key: key, value: value[key]});
    }
    return keys;
  }
}
and use it like that:

<span *ngFor="let entry of content | keys">           
  Key: {{entry.key}}, value: {{entry.value}}
</span>
```

Comment: need to import KeysPipe in your app.module.ts file or your root module.

Comment: can you send your array?

Comment: export class CapacitorBankFileComponent implements OnInit {
  capacitorBanks = []; this.subscriptions = this.cbank.getAssetServerAttributes(this.localCustomer, data[indexx]).subscribe(vres => {
            this.serverAttributes.push(vres[indexx]);
            indexx ++;
          });

Comment: please check in this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wdxcaa?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts