# Filter *ngFor from array object

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to filter only those objects whose `categoria` is `a`. Is there any way to achieve this using ngFor?

**service.ts :**

```
productos: Producto[] = [
  {id:'01', categoria:'a', titulo:'title1'},
  {id:'02', categoria:'b', titulo:'title2'},
  {id:'03', categoria:'a', titulo:'title3'},
  {id:'04', categoria:'c', titulo:'title4'},
  {id:'05', categoria:'c', titulo:'title5'}
]

getProductos() {
   return of(this.productos);
}
```

**component.ts :**

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.productos$ = this.ps.getProductos();
}
```

**component.html :**

```
<div *ngFor="let producto of productos$ | async">
  {{ producto.titulo}}
</div>
```

Comment: Can you write the question in English ?

Comment: I'm sorry, it's already translated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to apply filters to \*ngFor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34164413/how-to-apply-filters-to-ngfor)

Comment: @Vinit Agreed with you. I have raised the duplicate flag for this question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a pipe ( refer to Vinit link ) or you can use a filter

```
getProductos() {
   return of(this.productos.filter( el => el.categoria == 'a'); 
}
```

Comment: This is a very good alternative, it worked for me. Thank you. I think there is a typo, it ended up like this: `getProductos() { return of (this.productos.filter ( el => el.categoria === 'a'));}`

Answer (score 0):

You can use filter operator to do it.

```
ngOnInit() {
     this.productos$ = this.ps.getProductos().pipe(filter(el => el.categoria == 'a'));
}
```

Comment: This caused me an error in `filter`, after importing I generated another error in `categoria`

Comment: @Ashish Gurjar It would be good if there is any logic code inside ngOnInit(). We can put that logic code inside a method, then put this method inside the ngOnInit()

Comment: I just did a modification to the code that is posted with question.