# I want to remove an option whenever it is chosen angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

ex: I have ['a', 'b', 'c'] in the select tags, then ['b'] is chosen, I want the next select tag contains only ['a', 'c']

TS file:

```
orderSelect() { //get all documents from db
    this.orderService.orderSelect().subscribe(data => {
        this.orderArray = new MatTableDataSource(data); 
        this.orderArray.sort = this.sort;
        this.orderArray.paginator = this.paginator;
    });
}
```

HTML file:

```html
<mat-form-field> 
    <mat-select formControlName="productId" matInput placeholder="Product" #productId required>
        <mat-option *ngFor="let a of productArray" value="{{ a._id }}" (click)="getPrice(i, a.productPrice, a.productQuantity); getTotal(i)">{{ a.productName }}</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: what have you tried until now?

Comment: and what data the array `productArray` contains?

Comment: i used this code whenever it clicks an option in select tags this.productArray.splice(index, 1);

Comment: the array contains: router.get('/productSelect', (req, res, next) =>{
    productSchema.aggregate([   
        { $lookup:
            {
                from: 'supplierschemas',
                localField: 'supplierId',
                foreignField: '_id',
                as: 'supplier'
            }
        },

Comment: { $lookup:
            {
                from: 'brandschemas',
                localField: 'brandId',
                foreignField: '_id',
                as: 'brand'
            }
        },
        { $lookup:
            {
                from: 'categoryschemas',
                localField: 'categoryId',
                foreignField: '_id',
                as: 'category'
            }
        }
    
    ], (err, productSchema) =>{
        if(err) res.json(err);
        else res.json(productSchema);
    });
});

Comment: i tried this code: this.productArray.splice(index, 1); but it removes wrong element in array. then i wan to return the previous element when the deleted form is deleted. this is a reactive form. creates multiple form in a button click

Comment: My recommendation is to create a `Pipe`(filter) and use it in `ngFor`. See [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34164413/how-to-apply-filters-to-ngfor)