# How Can I sort a table (click) on the header?

Tags: angular, sorting, click

What's the kind of logic that I have to use for sort my elements?

Here I generate all of the columns and rows.

`dynamic-table.component.html`

```html
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th *ngFor="let col of columns" (click)="onClickSort()">{{col}}</th>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngFor="let user of users">
      <td *ngFor="let col of columns">{{user[col]}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

`dynamic-table.component.ts`

```ts
import {Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dynamic-table',
  templateUrl: './dynamic-table.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dynamic-table.component.css']
})
export class DynamicTableComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input()
  users = [];
  @Input()
  columns: string[];
  constructor() {
  }
  onClickSort() {
    //ADD LOGIC SORT
  }
  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

My datas are in a `mock.ts`, I can find them in my service.

`app.component.ts`

```ts
import {Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {TableService} from './table.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  users;
  columns;
  constructor(private atService: TableService) {
  }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.columns = this.atService.getColumns();
    this.atService.getUsers().subscribe((res) => this.users = res);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Nathan, as you can read, I can't use mat-sort-header, just an event Click and the method in the component with some sort logic.

I saw the documentation about mat-sort-header, but I'm a beginner so i have to use basic things.

Comment: Start with trying [Array.prototype.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) and sorting `columns` based on whatever conditions you would need.

Comment: Here I answer the question, it works for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54942025/10592616

Answer (score 2):

You could write a [pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34164413/how-to-apply-filters-to-ngfor) that takes in the data and returns the data sorted in the way you'd prefer.

```
<li *ngFor="let item of items | sortingPipe: filterarg">
```

And the `myfilter` pipe will do something like this:

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'sortingPipe'
})
export class SortingPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(myArr, filterArg) {

    const sorted = myArr.sort((x, y) => {
      return x.duration - y.duration; // whatever you want to compare
    });
    return sorted.slice(0);

  }
}
```

Comment: Isn't it possibile doing something easier directly in my component without creating anything new?

Comment: You can do it in a component too as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43524428/5017391

Comment: Yakubchick, I did this:

 sortTable(parm) {
    this.users.sort((a, b) => a[parm].localeCompare(b[parm]));
  }

But I can't reverse the Sort and I cant sort the numbers columns... why?

Comment: You might need a separate function that sorts in the other direction (swap `a` and `b` near the `localeCompare` word). If you need to reset to the original ordering, you might need to keep a copy of the original array (see the `.slice(0)` trick I used above).

Answer (score 0):

There's a good library for this

https://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/

It's very easy to use.

Just load the script in your html file and modify your header to add sortable (with one t) as a class, like this:

```
<script src="sorttable.js"></script>
 <table>
    <tr>
      <th *ngFor="let col of columns">{{col}}</th>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngFor="let user of users">
      <td *ngFor="let col of columns">{{user[col]}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: Do you know if it's possible doing something easier in my component without adding js?

Comment: This solution is already easy, just add 1 line to include the .js file, add a class to your existing html table and voila :)  what do you mean by easier? I personally believe reusing an existing library is probably better/faster than writing your own sorting functions. If you wish, you can also try using the sort api.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a fan of the [ngx-datatable](https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-datatable) - a library for beautiful tables with sorting and searching.

An example of [sorting](http://swimlane.github.io/ngx-datatable/#client-sorting) is just adding a single property to the `<ngx-datatable></<ngx-datatable>` component.