# filter a list of strings dynamically

Tags: javascript, angular

How can i dynamically filter a list of strings?

I found examples with `ng-repeat`, but it doesn't work with **angular 7**: it doesn't load any string, it works only with `ngFor`

```html
<div class="input-group">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <div class="input-group-text">Find ticket</div>
  </div>
  <input class="form-control" placeholder="Insert ticket to find" [(ngModel)]="find_text">
</div>
<ul class="list-group" style="max-height: 200px; overflow: auto;">
  <li class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let s of find_text">{{s.Value}}</li>  
</ul>
```

Comment: Try to use a pipe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34164413/how-to-apply-filters-to-ngfor

Comment: Can you tell us the filter you want and the sample input

Comment: angularjs's filters equivalent are `Pipes` in angular 2+. https://angular.io/guide/pipes . Sometimes, however, it's better to just filter the result set instead of using a pipe. Can you give us further informations about what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**With the help of pipe**

Html code:

```
<div class="input-group">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <div class="input-group-text">Find ticket</div>
  </div>
<input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="searchText" placeholder="Search item" name="search"
    autocomplete="off">
</div>
<ul class="list-group" style="max-height: 200px; overflow: auto;">
  <li class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let s of word_list| filterForUser : searchText">{{s.value}}</li>  
</ul>
```

Filter:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
@Pipe({
    name: 'filterForUser'
})
export class FilterPipeForUserSearch implements PipeTransform {
    transform(items: any[], searchText: string): any[] {
        if (!items || !searchText) return items;
        searchText = searchText.toLowerCase();
        // return items.filter(it => {
            return items.filter((data) => this.matchValue(data,searchText)); 
        // });
    }
    matchValue(data, value) {
        return Object.keys(data).map((key) => {
           return new RegExp(value, 'gi').test(data[key]);
        }).some(result => result);
      }
}
```

component:

```
private word_list = [{value:"Chiku"}, {value:"Apple"}, {value:"Banana"}, {value:"Pear"}, {value:"Bluebarry"}]
```

**Note**: Please declare `FilterPipeForUserSearch` in your app module.

Answer (score 1):

You're binding find_text as a string in ngModel and as a list of Objects in *ngFor directive.
I think this is what you're asking:

```js
public text;
private word_list = [{value:"Apple"}, {value:"Banana"}, {value:"Pear"}, {value:"Bluebarry"}]
get find_text(){
  return this.word_list.filter(x => x.value.toLowerCase().includes(text.toLowerCase()));
}
```

```html
<div class="input-group">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <div class="input-group-text">Find ticket</div>
  </div>
  <input class="form-control" placeholder="Insert ticket to find" [(ngModel)]="text">
</div>
<ul class="list-group" style="max-height: 200px; overflow: auto;">
  <li class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let s of find_text">{{s.value}}</li>  
</ul>
```