# How to use filter in “*ngFor” loop based on list of data

Tags: filter, angular6, pipe

It was done in angular 1.5 as follows with the following data

```
getdetailAttrList= [
    { getName: "Id", getNumber: "1335626187264778", getString: '10000450439458'},
    { getName: "Pat_Id", getNumber: "1335626196206806", getString: '00350242060011'},
    { getName: "Prov_Id", getNumber: "1335626218309875", getString: '3228610'},
    { getName: "Pat_Name", getNumber: "1335626212804143", getString: '200131'},

];

<tr ng-if="getdetailAttrList.length >= 0" 
ng-repeat="info in getdetailAttrList
| unique:'getName' | filter: { getName: '!UID' } 
| filter: { getName: '!PROVIDERID' }">
   <td class="subj">{{info.getName}}</td>
   <td>{{info.getString}}</td>
</tr>
```

How to achieve the same functionality in angular 6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In angular 6 you can loop your data by this way

```
<tr *ngIf="getdetailAttrList.length >= 0" *ngFor="let info of getdetailAttrList">
 <td class="subj">{{info.getName}}</td>
 <td>{{info.getString}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Yes. But how to apply this filter condition

Comment: check this [filter-data-angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34164413/how-to-apply-filters-to-ngfor)

Comment: Great, as your problem is resolved mark it as answered.