# Ionic 4 Display a specific key value from JSON

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am trying to display only a key value, in this case "_t1_product_price" from a JSON data array which looks as follows. I know that if I use ngFor keyPipe method in Angular6 it would just loop through all keys and values but that isn't what I am looking for to narrow down to a single object. Hoping someone could guide me out.

```html
meta_data: Array(17)
0: {id: 37609, key: "inline_featured_image", value: "0"}
1: {id: 37610, key: "erp-wc-subscription", value: Array(0)}
2: {id: 37619, key: "_inventory_asset_account", value: ""}
3: {id: 37620, key: "_item_sales", value: "0"}
4: {id: 37621, key: "_sales_account", value: ""}
5: {id: 37622, key: "_tax_on_sales", value: "-1"}
6: {id: 37623, key: "_item_purchase", value: "0"}
7: {id: 37624, key: "_purchase_price", value: ""}
8: {id: 37625, key: "_purchase_account", value: ""}
9: {id: 37626, key: "_tax_on_purchase", value: "-1"}
10: {id: 37627, key: "_cost_price", value: ""}
11: {id: 37628, key: "_sales_description", value: ""}
12: {id: 37629, key: "_purchase_description", value: ""}
13: {id: 37630, key: "_woo_uom_input", value: ""}
14: {id: 37900, key: "_t1_product_price", value: "1"}
15: {id: 37901, key: "_t2_product_price", value: "2"}
16: {id: 37902, key: "_t3_product_price", value: "3"}
```

And also what can I use as TypeScript to display the view. Currently I am using this method which isn't what I am looking for. Thanks in advance.

```html
<ion-item *ngFor="let item of product.meta_data">
              {{item.id}} - {{item.value}}
</ion-item>
```

Comment: do you mean you want to filter your object and returning only the key you want ? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34164413/how-to-apply-filters-to-ngfor

Comment: Do you want to extract only key and values from the objects?? If yes then you can use javascript array.map method.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question, you can filter the data at typescript level not at the template , You could use map function to get the single key value

```
    uniqueprice = metadata
            .map(function(product) {
    if(product.key == "_t1_product_price")
        {
          return product.key;
        }
         })
       console.log(uniqueprice);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `map` array method to map the array to a array having a single object and then extract that object using indexing.

```
metadata.map(data => data.key === 'yourkeytext' && data)[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a method to filter the object, which belongs to your key.

```
  <ion-item>
        {{ getObject(product.meta_data, key) .id}} - 
        {{getObject(product.meta_data,key).value}}
    </ion-item>

    private getObject(listOfObject, key)
    {
     return  listOfObject.filter(data=> data.key == key)
    }
```

Another way you can use pipe to get values from method, because this method may get call again and again which can make your application slow.

```
<ion-item>
              {{(item | MyPipe:key).id}} - {{(item | MyPipe:key).value}}
</ion-item>

export class MyPipe implements PipeTransform {    
        transform(value, key):any {  
               value.filter(data=> data.key == key)
        }
}
```