# Update array for ngFor template each 1 second interval

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, rxjs, observable, setinterval

I have an *ngFor property in my Ionic-angular template which is printing all objects of an array property. The thing is that this array can change, having more elements or even updating some attributes for the already present objects. Because of that, I'm requesting to my server the array each 1 seconds using rxjs, subscribing it and reassigning the server response to the array property again.

Above mentioned has as result that the view is re rendered each second which causes that the data is appearing and dissapearing constantly on screen.

How is the best way to deal with that? I know that the way of updating the array is pushing the elements. However, as the old objects can change their properties values I don't know how to continue working.

I will show you some simplified code snnipets:

**Interval subscription**

```
import { interval } from 'rxjs';
private subscription;
simulationsResponse;
//data is the property for *ngFor
data;
public intervallTimer = interval(1000);

ionViewWillEnter() {
    this.subscription = this.intervallTimer.subscribe(x => {

        this.dm.getAllSimulations().then(res => {
          this.simulationsResponse = res;
              this.data = this.simulationsResponse.simulators;

        });
    });
}
```

**Template**

```
<div class="listSimulations" *ngFor="let simulation of data">
    .
    .
    .
    .
</div>
```

Comment: Use trackBy https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf#ngForTrackBy

Comment: Do the values in your `data` array have any _identity_ property? a unique value that identifies any object individually?

Comment: @Jota.Toledo yes, _id property as I'm working with mongoose schemas

Comment: @Jota.Toledo Could you please give me an example of trackBy? Maybe this works for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to avoid angualar tearing down and recreating the whole DOM whenever you set a new array, you need to track the entries in the array using [trackBy](http://%20angular.io/api/common/NgForOf#ngForTrackBy):

```
interface Simulation {
  public _id: string;
  ...
}

interface SimulationResponse {
  public simulators: Simulation[];
  ...
}

import {TrackByFn} from '@angular/core';
import {interval, from} from 'rxjs';
import {mergeMap} from 'rxjs/operators';

private subscription;
simulationsResponse: SimulationResponse;
data: Simulation[];

ionViewWillEnter() {
    this.subscription = interval(1000)
                    .pipe(mergeMap(_=>from(this.dm.getAllSimulations()))
                   .subscribe(res => {
                       this.simulationsResponse = res;
                       this.data = res.simulators;
                   });

 trackSimulation: TrackByFn<Simulation> = simulation => simulation._id;
}

<div class="listSimulations" *ngFor="let simulation of data; trackBy: trackSimulation">
    .
    .
    .
    .
</div>
```

Comment: I'm having problems with your code. The function getAllSimulations() returns Promise<any> so the variable res of subscribe method is undefined

Comment: Updated, please check

Comment: It's almost working fine. The new element is showing in the view, but one of the old elements is not rendering. Something strange is happening, I've inspected the element with dev tools and the html and the data is there, but the result is a blank element. Do you have any idea of what can be this?

Comment: If you provide a small reproduction of your problem in stackblitz, then I might be able to look into it.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the behaviour in a small example. I don't know what is happening in my project but it's unbelievable. I could give some images, the data properties are in the dom but is not showing, it only shows an empty div

Comment: Ok, finally I found the bug, I had a conditional value for class attribute, deleting that works super nice, thank you so much!

Answer (score -2):

You'll need to write a your custom ngFor Pipe for this. In the pipe, you have stop the execution for 1 second.

Please refer to this answer to write your custom pipe. - https://stackoverflow.com/a/34165371/11928048

Comment: I don't understand how can filtering the array's elements can help me with my task. I need to display all elements