# Create a custom filter using FilterPredicate to filter DataSource

Tags: angular, typescript, predicate

I'm using a dataSource to store all my data. Until now, I was using the standard filter when performing a search. However, now I would like to perform searchs with the "OR" operator.

Example :

```
{name : john, age : 25, work : driver}

{name : peter, age : 28, work : writer}

{name : james, age : 39, work : athlete}
```

If I input "john james" I want the filter function to get me line 1 AND line 3.

I'm pretty sure we have to use a filterPredicate, but I really don't understand how to create/use those, and I couldn't find any decent/working example

The documentation would not help much besides giving me a protoype :

```
filterPredicate: ((data: T, filter: string) => boolean);
```

Do you guys have any idea or code example how to achieve that ?

Here is what my function looks like for now for a basic search :

```
  applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
    filterValue = filterValue.toLowerCase();
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue;
  }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to apply filters to \*ngFor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34164413/how-to-apply-filters-to-ngfor)

Comment: Definitely not, I'm trying to modify the default filtering method of a dataSource so that all my future searchs perform the way I want them to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const users = [
  {name : 'john', age : 25, work : 'driver'},
  {name : 'peter', age : 28, work : 'writer'},
  {name : 'james', age : 39, work : 'athlete'}
]

const query = "john james";

const filtered = users.filter(e => query.includes(e.name));
```

This should work :)

using DataSource:

```
this.dataSource.filterPredicate = (data, filter) => filter.includes(data.name)
```

Comment: Hello, I can't seem to apply your predicate to a dataSource. 
`this.dataSource.filter(e => filterValue.includes(e.name));` doesnt compile

Comment: 'this.dataSource.filterPredicate = (data, filter) => filter.includes(data.name);'

Comment: I found what was wrong, need to pass `this.dataSource.data`. Seems to be working now : 
`this.dataSource.filterPredicate = (data=this.dataSource.data, filter : string) => filter.includes(data.name)`
Thank you, your answer helped.