# How to filter JSON data in ngfor iteration and get the specified value in <td> in angular 9

Tags: html, json, angular, typescript, angular9

I am having a static defined data in JSON which i imported in my typscript. On the other side i have an ngFor iterated data in a table. My request is to compare the  value got from ngFor through api (mysql data). the each  value should get compare with the JSON data value or by filtering the JSON data with respect to the each iterated  value. Please look at my current code and help to make it working.

**html**

```
<table id="basic-datatables" class="display table table-striped table-hover" >
                <thead>
                  <tr align="center">
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Email ID</th>
                    <th>Designation</th>
                    <th>Department</th>
                    <th>Location</th>
                    <th>Access Control</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <tr *ngFor="let item of userlist" align="center">
                    <td id="userId">{{item.user_id}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.First_Name}} {{item.Last_Name}}</td>
                    <td >{{item.username}}</td>
                    <td >{{item.Designation}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.Department}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.Location}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.Access_Role}}</td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
```

**My ts Function**

```
    getUserlist(){
  // tslint:disable-next-line: deprecation
  console.log('Loggin Function');

  this.querySubscription = this._backendService.getUserlist().subscribe((res: { errorCode: number; errorMessage: string; }) => {
    if (res.errorCode > 0) {
        this.error = false;
        this.errorMessage = '';
        this.dataLoading = false;
        this.savedChanges = true;
        // tslint:disable-next-line: no-string-literal
        this.userlist = res['data'];
        this.userAccess.filter(e => (e.value) = this.userlist.Access_Role);
        this.userDepartment.filter(e => (e.value) = this.userlist.Department);
        this.userDesignation.filter(e => (e.value) = this.userlist.Designation);
        this.userLocation.filter(e => (e.value) = this.userlist.Location);
        console.log(this.userlist.Access_Role);
    } else {
        this.error = true;
        this.errorMessage = res.errorMessage;
        this.dataLoading = false;
    }
  });
}
```

**JSON data**

```
    {
  "user_access": [
     {
        "value": "1",
        "text": "Administrator"
     },
     {
        "value": "2",
        "text": "Dept Head"
     },
     {
        "value": "3",
        "text": "Staff"
     },
     {
        "value": "4",
        "text": "Customer"
     }
  ],
  "user_department": [
     {
        "value": "1",
        "text": "Sales"
     },
     {
        "value": "2",
        "text": "Production"
     },
     {
        "value": "3",
        "text": "Planning"
     },
     {
        "value": "4",
        "text": "Design"
     },
     {
        "value": "5",
        "text": "Operation"
     },
     {
        "value": "6",
        "text": "Purchase"
     },
     {
        "value": "7",
        "text": "Service"
     },
     {
        "value": "8",
        "text": "Quality"
     },
     {
        "value": "9",
        "text": "Finance"
     },
     {
        "value": "10",
        "text": "IT"
     }
  ],
  "user_designation": [
     {
        "value": "1",
        "text": "Director"
     },
     {
        "value": "2",
        "text": "Sr.Manager"
     },
     {
        "value": "3",
        "text": "Manager"
     },
     {
        "value": "4",
        "text": "Asst.Manager"
     },
     {
        "value": "5",
        "text": "Sr.Engineer"
     },
     {
        "value": "6",
        "text": "Engineer"
     },
     {
        "value": "7",
        "text": "Sr.Excecutive"
     },
     {
        "value": "8",
        "text": "Excecutive"
     },
     {
        "value": "9",
        "text": "Supervisor"
     }
  ],
  "user_location": [
     {
        "value": "1",
        "text": "Thiruvallur - Factory"
     },
     {
        "value": "2",
        "text": "Chennai - Sales"
     },
     {
        "value": "3",
        "text": "Banglore - Sales"
     },
     {
        "value": "4",
        "text": "Hyderabad - Sales"
     }
  ]
}
```

**Current Table in HTML view**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2xEd9.png)

**Actual Table in HTML view needed**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VckJf.png)

Comment: You can either use map function in your typescript and add extra properties or you can create some pipes to change these values to description. However, I will suggest by map and new properties.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Since i am begginer in typescript can u suggest an example

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you write a pipe which you can then use in the `*ngFor` directive.

In your component:

```js
filterargs = {title: 'hello'};
items = [{title: 'hello world'}, {title: 'hello kitty'}, {title: 'foo bar'}];
```

In your template, you can pass string, number or object to your pipe to use to filter on:

```
<li *ngFor="let item of items | myfilter:filterargs">
```

In your pipe:

```js
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'myfilter',
    pure: false
})
export class MyFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(items: any[], filter: Object): any {
        if (!items || !filter) {
            return items;
        }
        // filter items array, items which match and return true will be
        // kept, false will be filtered out
        return items.filter(item => item.title.indexOf(filter.title) !== -1);
    }
}
```

Link of [Main Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34164413/how-to-apply-filters-to-ngfor) about How to apply filters to *ngFor?