# How to remove the item which has ```CLOSED``` in ngFor in angular/

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

***TS***

```
  @Select(NotificationState.get('onDisplay')) onDisplay$: Observable<Array<Partial<Alert>>>;
```

***HTML***

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let notif of onDisplay$ | async; let i = index">
    <span>{{notif.name}}</span>
  </ng-container?>
```

the data is:

```
[{
    name: 'John',
    case: 'CLOSED'
},{
    name: 'Joshua',
    case: 'CLOSED'
},{
    name: 'Carl',
    case: 'NEW'
},{
    name: 'Jen',
    case: 'CLOSED'
}]
```

I'm using observable and what I'm trying to do is to remove the data which has `case: 'CLOSED'`.
How to remove the item have `CLOSED` from the array in ngFor?

Comment: You can write custom pipe to filter it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to apply filters to \*ngFor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34164413/how-to-apply-filters-to-ngfor)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6yeeqa) write custom pipe for this

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
@Pipe({
  name: 'closedPipe'
})

export class CustomPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(row: any[]): any {
      return row.filter(x=>x.case!="CLOSED");       
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `*ngIf` directive to show only properties with certain condition.

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let notif of onDisplay$ | async; let i = index">
  <span *ngIf="notif.case !== 'CLOSED'">{{notif.name}}</span>
</ng-container>
```