# Filter *ngFor results from a search box input

Tags: angular, filter, ngfor

I am looking for a simple way to filter the *ngFor results from a search box input. The same way as in AngularJS this would work: ng-model="searchBox" / ng-repeat="x in y | filter:searchBox"...

My code is:

```
<input type="text">
<article *ngFor="let x of y | async | reverse">
    <p>Name: {{x.firstName}} {{x.secondName}}, City: {{x.city}}, Phone: {{x.phone}}</p>
</article>
```

Comment: You mean like a custom filter?
if so, maybe this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34164413/how-to-apply-filters-to-ngfor

Comment: My goal is a little bit different - when you write "a" in the input every object that contains "a" in its values should be shown.

Answer (score 1):

In template

```
  <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="searchItem">
  <div *ngIf="(data$| async)?.length;" >
    <article *ngFor="let x of y | async | myFilter: searchItem">
     <p>Name: {{x.firstName}} {{x.secondName}}, City: {{x.city}}, Phone 
      {{x.phone}}</p>
    </article>
 ​</div>
```

The custom pipe

```
 transform(value: any[], ...args: any): any {
    let searchItem = ''
    if(args.length)  searchItem = args[0].toLowerCase()
    return value.filter((data:any)=> data.firstName.toLowerCase().includes(searchItem));
  }
```

you can change the key (data.firstName) to match whatever you would like to filter with.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is using `*ngIf` to filter your result without having to make a custome `pipe`, here's how your code would look like

```
<input type="text">
<article *ngFor="let x of y | async | reverse">
  <p *ngIf="x.param == yourFilteredValue">Name: {{x.firstName}} {{x.secondName}}, City: {{x.city}}, Phone: {{x.phone}}</p>
</article>
```

Or you could wrap your entire `article` body with a `div` having an `*ngIf` expression.

Comment: This solution kind of works but the idea is if there is a value "London" in the object and you write "Lon" to have it shown. With "==" it will be shown only if you write the full "London" in the input...

Comment: @Alex - Try the `.startsWith(yourFilteredValue)` on your param.
It should go something like this: `*ngIf="x.param.startsWith(yourValue)"`

Comment: Thanks I used your example with includes() and it did the job! Unfortunately I can not cast a vote because of my reputation. :)

Comment: @Alex - That's awesome! Glad to know that helped somehow.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try keeping the filter logic inside ts file and then return an array which contains the required items. Then you could loop them and display as needed.