# Angular: loop through an array of Objects and count length of array only if account-status is not complete

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, ngfor, angular-ng-if

I have an array of account-application with one of the three account-status (new, in-review, complete), I also have a button that should only show if the total number of new and in-review account-applications in the array are more than 20. Basically, the length of the array excluding the applications that set to complete.

I have searched online and tried a few of my own ideas but I am not able to find the right solution. I would be very grateful if you guys could assist.

Comment: use filter and get the length of that, like `arr.filter(f=>f.status == 'new' || 'in-review').length`

Comment: Chris answer is right but I think it is better to creating a pipe or structural directive for showing and hiding button.

Comment: thanks Chris, your suggestion is helpful.

Comment: @Mohammadreza Mohammadi, do you have a link for an example?

Comment: this link is for a pipe sample https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34164413/how-to-apply-filters-to-ngfor