# How to apply filters to *ngFor to filter objects using text input?

Tags: angular, typescript, ngfor

I am trying to create a filter so that every letter in the filter box dynamically filters the objects below. These objects are not in a `<li></li>` list. Each object has 4 fields: `experience_title`, `experience_descripton`, `contributed_by`, and `date`. They are displayed like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BBS9Y.png) using the code shown below:

```
<div class="row-md-4" *ngFor="let experience of experiences | searchFilter : searchTerm">
  <div class="card card-body">
    <h5>{{ experience.experience_title }}</h5>
    <p class="text-muted">{{ experience.experience_description }}</p>

    <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
      <div class="flex align-self-stretch ms-2">
        <i class="bi bi-person"></i>
      </div>

      <div class="flex-grow-1 ms-2 me-2">
        <p>{{ experience.contributed_by }}</p>
      </div>

      <div class="flex align-self-stretch">
        <i class="bi bi-calendar3"></i>
      </div>

      <div class="flex-grow-1 ms-2 me-2">
        <p>{{ experience.date }}</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
      <div class="mx-2">
        <i
          class="bi bi-pen"
          data-bs-toggle="modal"
          data-bs-target="#editExperienceModal"
          (click)="getExperienceDetails(experience)"
        ></i>
      </div>

      <div class="mx-2">
      <i
        class="bi bi-trash"
        (click)="deleteExperience(experience)"
      ></i>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The code for the input element for the filter is below:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
  <input
    name="searchTerm"
    class="col-md-6 form-control"
    type="text"
    [(ngModel)]="searchTerm"
    (keyup)="search($any($event.target).value)"
  />
</div>
```

The `search` function is defined as:

```
search(filterString: string) {
  this.experiences = this.experiences.filter((value: any) => {
    return value.date.toLowerCase().includes(filterString.toLowerCase());
  });
}
```

The filter pipe code is:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'searchFilter'
})
export class SearchFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(items: any[], filterQuery: any): any[] {
    if(!items) {
      return [];
    }
    
    if(!filterQuery) {
      return items;
    }

    return items.filter((item) => {
      item.date.toLowerCase().includes(filterQuery.toLowerCase());
    });
  }
}
```

My issue is that on entering any text in the filter text box, I am unable to get any experiences. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BBS9Y.png) is how the webpage looks before the filtering is used. And [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ketP0.png) is how it looks after I use the filter. As you can notice, I have used the date filter and the text in the filter textbox matches the date of the first object. However, as you can see, I am unable to view any filtered experiences. I have also looked at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34164413/how-to-apply-filters-to-ngfor) and many other similar articles but I did not find them helpful. Can anyone please let me know if I am making some silly error?

I am happy to provide any extra bit of code or info, if necessary.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: delete '(keyup)="search($any($event.target).value)" ' and use pure like @Pipe({
    name: 'searchFilter',
    pure: false
})

Comment: Hey Hamid, thanks for replying. Do you mean that I should remove that line completely and in the filter pipe file, add `pure: false`?
Don't I need to keep `(keyup)="search($any($event.target).value)"` as it is essential to register the keystrokes used in the filter box? Or am I missing something?