# Remove previous time in time dropdown in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have this time intervals value which is binded in dropdown

```
export const TimeInterval = [
  '00:01', '00:30', '01:00', '01:30', '02:00', '02:30', '03:00', '03:30', '04:00', '04:30', '05:00', '05:30', '06:00', '06:30', '07:00', '07:30', '08:00', '08:30', '09:00', '09:30', '10:00', '10:30', '11:00', '11:30', '12:00 ', '12:30',
  '13:00', '13:30', '14:00', '14:30', '15:00', '15:30', '16:00', '16:30', '17:00', '17:30', '18:00', '18:30', '19:00', '19:30', '20:00', '20:30', '21:00', '21:30', '22:00', '22:30', '23:00', '23:30','23:59'
];
```

in html component :

```
 <ng-select [clearable]="false" class="form-control input-field"
              formControlName="entryFromTime">
              <ng-option *ngFor="let timeval of timeInterval" [value]="timeval">
                {{ timeval | customtimeformat }}
              </ng-option>
            </ng-select>
```

custom pipe to show am/pm

```
  transform(value: string): string {
    // split the time string into hours and minutes
    const [hours, minutes] = value.split(':');

    // convert the hours to 12-hour format
    let formattedHours = parseInt(hours, 10);
    const ampm = formattedHours >= 12 ? 'PM' : 'AM';
    formattedHours = formattedHours % 12;
    formattedHours = formattedHours ? formattedHours : 12;

    return `${formattedHours}:${minutes} ${ampm}`;
  }
```

this is working, i want to remove previous time if current time if 05:00 AM then before that time values should not be binded in dropdown

Any solution Thanks

Comment: You can use a filter in `ngFor`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to apply filters to \*ngFor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34164413/how-to-apply-filters-to-ngfor)

Answer (score 0):

You could filter the data: get the current time, as they're strings, compare them, and then leave only strings that are greater, and send that filtered array to ngFor:

```
  get timeInterval() {
    const date = new Date();
    const currentInterval = `${date.getHours().toString().padStart(2, '0')}:${date.getMinutes().toString().padStart(2, '0')}`;
    return TimeInterval.sort().filter(el=>el>currentInterval);
  }
```