# *ngIf and *ngFor on same element causing error

Tags: angular, ngfor, angular-ng-if

I'm having a problem with trying to use Angular's `*ngFor` and `*ngIf` on the same element.

When trying to loop through the collection in the `*ngFor`, the collection is seen as `null` and consequently fails when trying to access its properties in the template.

```ts
@Component({
  selector: 'shell',
  template: `
    <h3>Shell</h3><button (click)="toggle()">Toggle!</button>

    <div *ngIf="show" *ngFor="let thing of stuff">
      {{log(thing)}}
      <span>{{thing.name}}</span>
    </div>
  `
})

export class ShellComponent implements OnInit {

  public stuff:any[] = [];
  public show:boolean = false;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.stuff = [
      { name: 'abc', id: 1 },
      { name: 'huo', id: 2 },
      { name: 'bar', id: 3 },
      { name: 'foo', id: 4 },
      { name: 'thing', id: 5 },
      { name: 'other', id: 6 },
    ]
  }

  toggle() {
    this.show = !this.show;
  }

  log(thing) {
    console.log(thing);
  }

}
```

I know the easy solution is to move the `*ngIf` up a level but for scenarios like looping over list items in a `ul`, I'd end up with either an empty `li` if the collection is empty, or my `li`s wrapped in redundant container elements.

Example at this [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/C5tZ8mD3iWczVvWkWycH?p=preview).

Note the console error:

```
EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null in [{{thing.name}} in ShellComponent@5:12]
```

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40529537/ng2-difference-between-ng-container-and-ng-template-tags

i'd go with ng-container

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular filtered table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42385691/angular-filtered-table)

Answer (score 909, accepted):

Angular v2 doesn't support more than one structural directive on the same element.
As a workaround use the **`<ng-container>`** element that allows you to use separate elements for each structural directive, but it is **not stamped to the DOM**.

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="show">
  <div *ngFor="let thing of stuff">
    {{log(thing)}}
    <span>{{thing.name}}</span>
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

**Updates for Angular v17 and beyond**

The `<ng-container>` approach can no longer be recommended, since the introduction of the control flow in Angular v17.

```html
@if(show){
  @for(thing of stuff; track thing.id){
  <div>
    {{log(thing)}}
    <span>{{thing.name}}</span>
  </div>
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Surprisingly is still undocumented: https://github.com/angular/angular.io/issues/2303

Comment: How will code look like when we have to have *ngIf inside *ngFor ? I.e. IF condition will be based on value of a loop element.

Comment: Just put `ngFor` at the `<ng-container>` element and the `ngIf` at the `<div>`. You can also have two nested `<ng-container>` wrapping the `<div>`. `<ng-container>` is just a helper element that will not be added to the DOM.

Comment: @user3640967 I agree with both. There is a lot of documentation but ng-container seems too much-needed functionality for everyone, should be better documented, Don't you think?

Comment: `<md-autocomplete #auto="mdAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn">
            <template *ngIf="!selectedCategories.includes(category)">
                <md-option *ngFor="let category of categories"
                    [value]="category" (onSelectionChange)="selectCategory($event, category.id)">
                    {{ category.title }}
                </md-option>
            </template>
        </md-autocomplete>`
It shows nothing in my case. If I just ngFor over md-option (without the <template *ngIf="">, I actually have options... Sorry, but it doesn't do multiline here

Comment: `*ngIf` doesn't work on `<template>`. Either use `[ngIf]="..."` or `<ng-container *ngIf="..."`

Comment: Yup, it's a single ` and no space after it.
I've just realized, used [ngIf]. It works if I explicitly put `true` or `false`. So, there must be a problem with my `!selectedCategories.includes(category)` condition (selectedCategories is an array of objects, of the `category` form - `{"id": 1, "title": "Some title"}`
Anyway, I'm already off topic. Using <template> should work.

Comment: I'd suggest using `<ng-container>`. It behaves the same as `<template>` but allows to use the "normal" syntax for structural directives.

Comment: [Documentation says](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives): "One structural directive per host element": "There's an easy solution for this use case: put the *ngIf on a container element that wraps the *ngFor element." - just reiterating

Comment: @heringer thanks for the link. Such docs didn't exist back then when I posted this answer though :D

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Yeah, i realized that. I'm just updating the thread for future reference :)

Comment: Awesome answer. Fairly the answer everyone should be looking for.

Comment: Great! The best thing is (conditional rendering + not stamping to DOM).
[Docs: one-structural-directive-per-element](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#one-structural-directive-per-element)

Answer (score 110):

As everyone pointed out even though having multiple template directives in a single element works in angular 1.x it is not allowed in Angular 2. 
you can find more info from here : https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7315

## 2016 angular 2 beta

solution is to use the `<template>` as a placeholder, so the code goes like this

```
<template *ngFor="let nav_link of defaultLinks"  >
   <li *ngIf="nav_link.visible">
       .....
   </li>
</template>
```

but for some reason above does not work in `2.0.0-rc.4` in that case you can use this

```
<template ngFor let-nav_link [ngForOf]="defaultLinks" >
   <li *ngIf="nav_link.visible">
       .....
   </li> 
</template>
```

## Updated Answer 2018

With updates, right now in 2018 angular v6 recommend to use `<ng-container>` instead of `<template>`

so here is the updated answer.

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let nav_link of defaultLinks" >
   <li *ngIf="nav_link.visible">
       .....
   </li> 
</ng-container>
```

Comment: You saved my day, thank you.
one question why ```ng-container``` doesn't show HTML impact with styling and all

Answer (score 29):

As @Zyzle mentioned, and @Günter mentioned in a comment (https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7315), this is not supported.

With

```
<ul *ngIf="show">
  <li *ngFor="let thing of stuff">
    {{log(thing)}}
    <span>{{thing.name}}</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

there are no empty `<li>` elements when the list is empty.  Even the `<ul>` element does not exist (as expected).

When the list is populated, there are no redundant container elements.

The [github discussion (4792)](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4792) that @Zyzle mentioned in his comment also presents another solution using `<template>` (below I'm using your original markup ‐ using `<div>`s):

```
<template [ngIf]="show">
  <div *ngFor="let thing of stuff">
    {{log(thing)}}
    <span>{{thing.name}}</span>
  </div>
</template>
```

This solution also does not introduce any extra/redundant container elements.

Comment: I'm not sure why this isn't the accepted answer. `<template>` is the way to add a parent element that won't show up in the output.

Answer (score 11):

I solve my problem with this

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of menuItems">
  <li *ngIf="canShowItem(item)"></li>
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 9):

in html:

```
<div [ngClass]="{'disabled-field': !show}" *ngFor="let thing of stuff">
    {{thing.name}}
</div>
```

in css:

```
.disabled-field {
    pointer-events: none;
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

This will work but the element will still in the DOM.

```css
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

---

```html
<div [class.hidden]="!show" *ngFor="let thing of stuff">
    {{log(thing)}}
    <span>{{thing.name}}</span>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a very easy hack for <select> <option> combination, which I simply want to show filtered items instead of the full list

Answer (score 6):

You can not use more than one `Structural Directive` in Angular on the same element, it makes a bad confusion and structure, so you need to apply them in 2 separate nested elements(or you can use `ng-container`), read this statement from Angular team:

> **One structural directive per host element**
>
> Someday you'll want to repeat a block of HTML but only when a
>   particular condition is true. You'll try to put both an ***ngFor** and
>   an ***ngIf** on the same host element. Angular won't let you. You may
>   apply only one structural directive to an element.
>
> The reason is simplicity. Structural directives can do complex things
>   with the host element and its descendents. When two directives lay
>   claim to the same host element, which one takes precedence? Which
>   should go first, the NgIf or the NgFor? Can the NgIf cancel the effect
>   of the NgFor? If so (and it seems like it should be so), how should
>   Angular generalize the ability to cancel for other structural
>   directives?
>
> There are no easy answers to these questions. Prohibiting multiple
>   structural directives makes them moot. There's an easy solution for
>   this use case: put the ***ngIf** on a container element that wraps the
>   ***ngFor** element. One or both elements can be an **ng-container** so you don't have to introduce extra levels of HTML.

So you can use `ng-container` (Angular4) as the wrapper (will be deleted from the dom) or a div or span if you have class or some other attributes as below:

```
<div class="right" *ngIf="show">
  <div *ngFor="let thing of stuff">
    {{log(thing)}}
    <span>{{thing.name}}</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can't have `ngFor` and `ngIf` on the same element. What you could do is hold off on populating the array you're using in `ngFor` until the toggle in your example is clicked.

Here's a basic (not great) way you could do it: http://plnkr.co/edit/Pylx5HSWIZ7ahoC7wT6P

Comment: Why he cant have both? Elaborate please

Comment: There's a discussion around that here https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4792

Comment: I know why that's happening, it's just to improve quality of the answer, plainly saying `you can't` is not really a good answer, wont you agree?

Comment: Sure, they shouldn't be used together just because putting them in certain order to template doesn't guarantee that they will be executed in the same order. But this does not explain what exactly happens when 'Cannot read property 'name' of null' is thrown.

Comment: Both *ngFor and *ngIf (with asterisk) are structural directives and they generate <template> tag. Structural directives, like ngIf, do their magic by using the HTML 5 template tag.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use **`ng-template`** (instead of template. See the note for the caveat of using template tag) for applying both ***ngFor** and **ngIf** on the same HTML element. Here is an example where you can use **both *ngIf and *ngFor** for the same **tr** element in the angular table.

```
<tr *ngFor = "let fruit of fruiArray">
    <ng-template [ngIf] = "fruit=='apple'>
        <td> I love apples!</td>
    </ng-template>
</tr>
```

where `fruiArray = ['apple', 'banana', 'mango', 'pineapple']`.

**Note:**

The caveat of using just the `template` tag instead of **`ng-template`** tag is that it throws `StaticInjectionError` in some places.

Comment: Looks like a neat solution!

Comment: Thank you @ankush981

Answer (score 4):

I didn't want to wrap my `*ngFor` into another `div` with `*ngIf` or use `[ngClass]`, so I created a pipe named `show`:

show.pipe.ts

```js
export class ShowPipe implements PipeTransform {    
  transform(values: any[], show: boolean): any[] {
    if (!show) {
      return[];
    }
    return values;
  }
}
```

any.page.html

```html
<table>
  <tr *ngFor="let arr of anyArray | show : ngIfCondition">
    <td>{{arr.label}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

## Updated to angular2 beta 8

Now as from angular2 beta 8 we can use `*ngIf` and `*ngFor` on same component [see here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6304).

Alternate:

Sometimes we can't use HTML tags inside another like in `tr`, `th` (`table`) or in `li` (`ul`). We cannot use another HTML tag but we have to perform some action in same situation so we can HTML5 feature tag `<template>` in this way.

## ngFor using template:

```
<template ngFor #abc [ngForOf]="someArray">
    code here....
</template>
```

## ngIf using template:

```
<template [ngIf]="show">
    code here....
</template>
```

For more information about structural directives in angular2 [see here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/structural-directives.html#).

Answer (score 3):

Table below only lists items that have a "beginner" value set.
Requires both the `*ngFor` and the `*ngIf` to prevent unwanted rows in html.

Originally had `*ngIf` and `*ngFor` on the same `<tr>` tag, but doesn't work.
Added a `<div>` for the `*ngFor` loop and placed `*ngIf` in the `<tr>` tag, works as expected.

```
<table class="table lessons-list card card-strong ">
  <tbody>
  <div *ngFor="let lesson of lessons" >
   <tr *ngIf="lesson.isBeginner">
    <!-- next line doesn't work -->
    <!-- <tr *ngFor="let lesson of lessons" *ngIf="lesson.isBeginner"> -->
    <td class="lesson-title">{{lesson.description}}</td>
    <td class="duration">
      <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>
      <span>{{lesson.duration}}</span>
    </td>
   </tr>
  </div>
  </tbody>

</table>
```

Comment: I don't think a `<div>` inside a table is a goos idea, especially when there are better alternatives. Have you checked if thus works in IE which is especially picky about elements in `<table>`

Answer (score 1):

```
<div *ngFor="let thing of show ? stuff : []">
  {{log(thing)}}
  <span>{{thing.name}}</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

On other solution might be to put an empty array in your for loop in the case where you don't want to display it

```
<div *ngFor="let thing of show ? stuff : []">
```

Where "stuff" is an array of "thing" and "show" the boolean to display or not the content

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!-- Since angular2 stable release multiple directives are not supported on a single element(from the docs) still you can use it like below -->


<ul class="list-group">
                <template ngFor let-item [ngForOf]="stuff" [ngForTrackBy]="trackBy_stuff">
                    <li *ngIf="item.name" class="list-group-item">{{item.name}}</li>
                </template>
   </ul>
```

Comment: li items are only displayed if it has a name.

Comment: How does this answer add value here? It doesn't provide anything that's not provided by the other answers already or did I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use multiple structural directive on same element. Wrap your element in `ng-template` and use one structural directive there

Answer (score 0):

You can do this another way by checking the array length

```
<div *ngIf="stuff.length>0">
  <div *ngFor="let thing of stuff">
    {{log(thing)}}
    <span>{{thing.name}}</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can two structural directives work together if one of them is *ngIf ?

No, you can't use multiple structural directives on same element If any of the directive is *ngIf then other directives will fail.

To avoid this directive failure, either you can use *ngSwitch or use ng-container tag for the loop and inside you can use ngIf to have a working code

Like below

```
    <ng-container *ngFor="let e of emp;">
        <tr *ngIf="e.name == txtname.value">
            <td>{{ e.name }}</td>
        </tr>
    </ng-container>
```

Answer (score -1):

With **angular 17**, the question is deprecated since *ngIf and *ngFor are replaced by the new syntax:

```html
@if(...){}
@for(...){}
```