# Angular 2 directive execution order

Tags: angular

Suppose you have `*ngIf` and `*ngFor` directives on one element. It makes much difference about the order directives are executed.

One way it will execute *ngFor one thousand times and check *ngIf for each iteration.

Another one will be checking *ngIf once and do nothing in case false result.

Not being able to use both directives on one element yields to non-essential markup getting into my code?

Why does angular doesn't define the order directives should be executed? It seems stupid!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Suppose you have `*ngIf` and `*ngFor` directives on one element

that's not supported. For more details see [*ngIf and *ngFor on same element causing error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34657821/ngif-and-ngfor-on-same-element-causing-error)

At least for this case there is no requirement to specify an execution order.