# *ngFor: last index of the loop is null

Tags: angular, iteration, ngfor

This is my code in a minimal form:

```
<div>
    {{ 'This is all comments Array =>'}}<br> 
    {{selectedPost.comments}}
    <div *ngIf="!commentsLoading" *ngFor="#comment of selectedPost.comments">
            {{ 'This is comment Object => ' + comment }}
    </div>
</div>
```

The comments is an array which has 5 objects outside the `*ngFor`. It iterates 6 times inside the loop and the last index becomes null.

*Output*

[image]

**Edit**
*Console*

[image]

Does anyone know what's happening?

Comment: Do `console.debug(selectedPost.comments)` and see what is in there.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin The console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the problem but I don't know why such thing is happening. I moved the `*ngIf="!commentsLoading"` one level up like this and the problem solved.

```
<div *ngIf="!commentsLoading">
  {{ 'This is all comments Array =>'}}<br> 
  {{selectedPost.comments}}
  <div *ngFor="#comment of selectedPost.comments">
        {{ 'This is comment Object => ' + comment }}
  </div>
</div>
```

I guess it causes problem when I use `*ngFor` and `*ngIf` together in one element in order to this issue: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7315

Comment: Yeah, I was about to comment that you cannot have 2 asterisks in the same line, but could not find the reference.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin Yes there is nothing about it I guess.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34657821/ngif-and-ngfor-on-same-element-causing-error check this out

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a json pipe after your debug output to see the actual content of the array.

```
{{selectedPost.comments | json}}
```