# Why is ngIf not working in angularjs2

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to use ngIf within an ngFor but it's just breaking my code. Below is my code:

```
<ion-row *ngIf="{{i % 3}}===0" *ngFor="let category of categories; let i=index">
```

I need to check if the index mod 3 is equal to zero

Comment: Do you try to use ngIf on the same element as the ngfor? and there is no code

Comment: Where is the code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [\*ngIf and \*ngFor on same element causing error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34657821/ngif-and-ngfor-on-same-element-causing-error)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can overwrite your code like:

```
<ion-row *ngFor="let category of categories; let i=index">
  <ng-container *ngIf="{{i % 3}}===0">
    ...
  </ng-container>
</ion-row>
```

`ng-container` behaves the same as `template` but you can use common syntax like `*ngIf` and `*ngFor`

Answer (score 0):

you can't put ngIf on the same component as ngFor

Comment: @MarkAdesina Angular 1 is very different than 2.

Answer (score 0):

1. Angular disallows such construction
2. Using `i` before initializing it in ngFor will never work
3. If you  *ngIf gets a false value the *ngFor would never be created in the first place - see point 1:-)