# How do you set dynamic components to a template?

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-components

Some background, if you want to skip to the real question, scroll down :-).

I have two `array`s of `object`s
One defining fields to be shown in an table, and one that defines each row with each field as well as some metadata, in this case `inputs`

```
headers = [
    {
        field: 'a'
    },
    {
        field: 'b'
    }
]

rows = [
    {
        a: "foo", 
        b: "bar", 
        inputs: false
    },
    {
        a: "foo",
        b: "bar", 
        inputs: true
    }
]
```

Each `object` in `rows` will be iterated, as well as each `object` in `headers`

```
<table>
    <tr *ngFor="let row of rows">
        <td *ngFor="let cell of headers" [innerHtml]="row[cell.field]">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

As long, all is fine. 
But if I want dynamic input fields depending on `row.inputs` value - how should that be solved?

using two sets of `<td>` with `*ngIf="row.inputs"` (and vice versa) gives me this error:

> Can't have multiple template bindings on one element. Use only one attribute named 'template' or prefixed with *...

That's a bummer, but I get it.

**The question**

In the best of worlds, I would want to use a function in for the innerHtml, which returns an Input Component, but how would that look like?

For example:

In my `Component` i add a function called `getDataOrInput`

```
  getDataOrInput(row, field): string | HTMLElement {
    if(row.inputs){
        /* 
        * Generate a Component based on field, and return HTML ?  
        */
    } else {
        return row[field]
    }
}
```

And in the HTML

```
<table>
    <tr *ngFor="let row of rows">
        <td *ngFor="let cell of headers" 
            [innerHtml]="getDataOrInput(row,cell.field)">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an easy workaround for your error message [*ngIf and *ngFor on same element causing error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34657821/ngif-and-ngfor-on-same-element-causing-error)

An alternative approach for dynamic components is explained in [Angular 2 dynamic tabs with user-click chosen components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325212/angular-2-dynamic-tabs-with-user-click-chosen-components/36325468#36325468)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to generate a component based on a field your best bet might be to create a structural directive.

for example:

```
const factory = this._resolver.resolveComponentFactory(**SomeComponent**);

// Make the Component with a factory and index (tells angular where to place component)

const componentRef = this._viewContainer.createComponent(factory, i);

// then you can tap into the instance of that component like so:
componentRef.instance.[**SomeInputName**]
```