# Nested *ngFor* with *ngIf

Tags: html, angular, angular-ng-if, ngfor, angular-material2

#### Problem

In the following code, I'm trying to display all `Projects` ( Objects ) under the `Tab` they're meant to go based on their category.

Category has to be equivalent.

EDIT: If that's not clear, take a look [here](https://yannosx.github.io/website/projects).

#### Here's my code:

```
<md-tab-group>
    <md-tab *ngFor="let tab of tabs">

        <template md-tab-label>
            {{tab.name}}
        </template>

        <h1 *ngFor="let project of projects" *ngIf="tab.category == project.category">
            Project Name: {{project.name}}
        </h1>

    </md-tab>
</md-tab-group>
```

#### What I'm trying to achieve:

I'm trying to iterate through tabs and add each tab's name to the "template" of the tab.

Then, I'm trying to iterate through projects and if the project's category matches the tab's category, then it will be displayed under the tab.

#### Me

For some reason it doesn't seem to work. Am I doing something wrong ?
Excuse me and my logic, been awake for the past 2 days!

Comment: do the casings match on the `category`? or are they numeric values

Comment: It doesn't work because you can't have 2 structural directives with asterisk in the same directive.

Comment: I guess you looking for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34164413/how-to-apply-filters-to-ngfor

Comment: Oops, meant to use `===` as they're both strings.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`*ngIf` and `*ngFor` (or in general more than one structural directive) on one element is not supported.

You can use the helper element `<ng-container>` to apply `*ngIf` and `*ngFor` to two different elements without another element being added to the DOM

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let project of projects">
  <h1 *ngIf="tab.category == project.category">
      Project Name: {{project.name}}
  </h1>
</ng-container>
```

See also [*ngIf and *ngFor on same element causing error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34657821/ngif-and-ngfor-on-same-element-causing-error/39565934#39565934)

Comment: Thank you, that's what I was looking for. I kind of suspected that was the reason. EDIT: I will accept your answer in 6 mins.