# How to Implement an Angular 2 content wrapper Directive (like jQuery's wrapInner)

Tags: angular, angular2-directives, wrapinner

I would like to implement an Angular 2 directive that behaves like [jQuery's `wrapInner` method](http://api.jquery.com/wrapinner/).
The library I'm writing will use angular 2+ only (no jQuery).

Basically, the directive will take the content of the element or component it has been applied to, and wrap that content in a div (or perhaps wrap it in some other html tag that's passed in as a parameter)

For example,

```
<myComponent wrapInner>
   ... All The Content ...
</myComponent>
```

should result in something like,

```
<myComponent >
   <div class="innerStyles" >
      ... All The Content ...
   </div>
</myComponent>
```

I am not sure what the most angular-style 'idiomatic' approach to this, as it seems to involves manipulating the DOM which is [discouraged](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/security.html#!#avoid-direct-use-of-the-dom-apis).

So could this perhaps be something that is better off being a Structural directive? Or involve manipulating [`templates`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/TemplateRef-class.html) or using [`ViewContainer`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ViewContainerRef-class.html) in some way? I dont know how to use those.

However, I have put together a plunker where I use the ([discouraged](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/security.html#!#avoid-direct-use-of-the-dom-apis)) insecure and inefficient way of going about this; by manipulating DOM through [`ElementRef`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ElementRef-class.html).

> https://plnkr.co/edit/PyVyzv3KUQ8IcsdNnVt0

Kindly Assist.
I really appreciate it!

Comment: Just ignore that `ElementRef` is insecure. It's not more insecure that using jQuery. " do not automatically protect you from security vulnerabilities" means that you are not automatically secured by Angular. If you take care that you are not doing things that cause security issues yourself, it's perfectly secure.

Comment: It's not just security that's a problem... in my plunker I found I had to manually loop through and add every child, grand child, great-grand-child .. node of every kind.. if their several layers of nested nodes this will become  efficiency nightmare I imagine

Comment: There is nothing Angular2 provides. You can search if there are some JS approaches that make it easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible at the moment.
But the Angular team has this feature on backlog.

You can follow progress at https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8785

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to do it without direct DOM manipulation.

To make this work you would need a component and use it like

```
<myComponent wrapInner>
  <wrap-inner>
   ... All The Content ...
  </wrapInnter>
</myComponent>
```

but there is no way to get rid of `<wrap-inner>` around the wrapper part (`<div class="innerStyles" >`)

Comment: Thanks for quick feedback Günter . wrapInner can to only be a single directive (potentially a structural one).. if I could use components then I'd just use ng-content  and that'd be pretty simple ... What I am trying to do is essentially emulate the ng-content functionality in a directive

Comment: If you want to use a directive, you are stuck with the approach you're already using.

Comment: Hmm.. well that's surprising. I am thinking along the lines of that if Component decorator inherits Directive decorator, And Component somehow has the ng-content feature (even though that's not itself a directive) then it should, in worst case scenario, be possible to essentially write your own ng-content type thing that works exclusive with directives ... Since well one was written for component directives .. does that make sense?

Comment: I somehow doubt the ng-content source uses this sort of bruteforce thing in my plunker

Comment: A component has a view, a directive doesn't. I don't know how `<ng-content>` is implemented. It might be easier if you pass the content as `<template>... All The Content ...</template>` then you can use `<template [ngTemplateOutlet]="myTemplate"`, but this again would need a view. You can stamp a template from a directive as well though. That's not too complated. `ViewContainerRef.createEmbeddedView()` does this as far as I remember and getting a `ViewContainerRef` in a directive is not difficult.

Comment: Yes I stumbled on ViewContainerRef` while exploring if I could make this work as a structural directive.. Desugaring structural directive seems to wrap `<template>` around wherever you apply the sdirective. However it looks like my use case would require that `template` to be wrapped inside the thing its applied to but around the content. Am I missing something here in the way i'm thinking about how structural derivatives work?

Comment: Also `Renderer.createTemplateAnchor()` seems to dynamically be able to create a template .. is this the type of template you are referring to that I might need?

Comment: If you make it a structural directive, then `<myComponent wrapInner>
   ... All The Content ...
</myComponent>  ` becomes `<template wrapInner><myComponent>
   ... All The Content ...
</myComponent><template>`. Then you still don't have the content you actually want to stamp as template (it contains `<myComponent>` which you probably don't want) and therefore can't stamp it directly.

Comment: Hard to tell what `Renderer.createTemplateAnchor()` does from this huge amount of documentation it provides ;-). If you get an instance of `TemplateRef`, then it should work.

Comment: Well this "vast" amount of documentation is exactly why i've taken to stack, I  dont know who else to ask .. haha... hopefully someone who has experimented more in these unchartered areas will see this quesiton!

Comment: Maybe I put in a feature request for syntactic sugar device that places the template *inside* the host rather than outside .. haha

Comment: Unlikely that will happen :D, but it would be nice to get the content of a component as `TemplateRef` without explicitly wrapping it with a `<template>` element.

Comment: Yes, that would be great too! hmm.. i dont want to force my users to explicitly have to <template> wrap  the content as well (that's kind of a pain )

Comment: You could use a structural directive on the content. That's a bit less pain, but not much.

Comment: wrapping `ng-container` around the content first.. ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean? I mean `<myComponent>
  <div *wrapInner> ... All The Content ...</div>
</myComponent>`. The `<div>` can be any other element that is the outermost element of "All The Content".

Comment: by the way just so you know, the reason I am insisting on using directive instead of component for `[wrapInner]` is because if I wrote it as a compoenent (even with the same attribut selector) I wouldn't be able to apply it to other components (e.g. as I have done in the example on plunker).. I could only apply it to naitive html elements.. Whereas I can apply directive to components and elements.. Am I misunderstanding how that works? is there some way to apply a component to another component.??

Comment: oh! what I meant was `<myComponent> <ng-container *wrapInner> ... All The Content ...</ng-container> </myComponent>`

Comment: That's right, you can't apply a component to another component. My suggestion was because you either need a component or a template element to have a way to place the content somewhere. Is there a reason you apply it to a component? The `wrapInner` attribute would need to be added by the user anyway. Why not adding it to the content instead as mentioned in my last comment?

Comment: You can use `<ng-container>` or `<template>` or add the directive selector to the outermost element of the content. `<ng-container>` is helpful if the outermost element already has a structural directive like `*ngIf` or `*ngFor` applied. You can only have one structural directive per element.

Comment: Oh I didn't know you can only have one sDirective per element.. thanks.. I'll think about your idea wrapping the div inside and putting a structural directive there...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34657821/ngif-and-ngfor-on-same-element-causing-error