# Angular filtered table

Tags: angular, templates, angularjs-filter

I have this totally legit data source:

```
public data = [
  { Field1: 1, Field2: 'One' },
  { Field1: 2, Field2: 'Two' },
  { Field1: 3, Field2: 'Three' },
  { Field1: 4, Field2: 'Four' }
];
```

I'm displaying it in a table like this:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>Field1</th>
    <th>Field2</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let item of data">
      <td>{{item.Field1}}</td>
      <td>{{item.Field2}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Now suppose I want to filter my array. If I had a fixed number of rows, I could elect to show/not show an item using `*ngIf` on the `tr` elements, but Angular doesn't allow two structural directives on one element.

I'm aware I can simply filter the source array using `Array.filter`, but that makes a copy, which may be an issue if my array is much bigger.

I thought of nesting the row in something (`div`, maybe?), but I'm not certain that is valid HTML.

So what is the correct way to dynamically filter data using Angular 2?

Comment: You can write your own `Pipe` to show filtered result on view..

Comment: ng-container or template might help you

Comment: @PankajParkar The Angular docs warns against this due to performance concerns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>Field1</th>
    <th>Field2</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let item of data">
      <tr *ngIf="someCondition">
         <td>{{item.Field1}}</td>
         <td>{{item.Field2}}</td>
      </tr>
    </ng-container>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Okay, that is just brilliant. I had to go look up ng-container, and it is "a logical container that can be used to group nodes but is not rendered in the DOM tree as a node." That's perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Possible ways:

- using a `Pipe` -> you don't need a copy
- using a filtered array

Angular prefers the way of filtering that data into another "copy".

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html#!#no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe-

Reasons are performance and minifiying..

So its up to you. :)

If you need any examples, give me a comment and i'll give you a plunker.