# how to render array of images in html view?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

Have below List of strings which contains images. How I can show it on page in the angular?

```
images: "[
  "https://images.oyoroomscdn.com/uploads/hotel_image/1097/340ea5ee01acc37f.jpg",
  "https://images.oyoroomscdn.com/uploads/hotel_image/1097/9b75ea873012234c.jpg",
  "https://images.oyoroomscdn.com/uploads/hotel_image/1097/d12b3a343f16cb28.jpg",
  "https://images.oyoroomscdn.com/uploads/hotel_image/1097/ff80cdc13a9832df.jpg",
  "https://images.oyoroomscdn.com/uploads/hotel_image/1097/c11025d7f461121b.jpg",
  "https://images.oyoroomscdn.com/uploads/hotel_image/1097/bb783cf9a2b1f35b.jpg",
  "https://images.oyoroomscdn.com/uploads/hotel_image/1097/3d68e6affdf43c18.jpg",
  "https://images.oyoroomscdn.com/uploads/hotel_image/1097/0fbd36321cf49f40.jpg",
  "https://images.oyoroomscdn.com/uploads/hotel_image/1097/63ef79df1ffcfef5.jpg",
  "https://images.oyoroomscdn.com/uploads/hotel_image/1097/acc162dea7861b9b.jpg",
  "https://images.oyoroomscdn.com/uploads/hotel_image/1097/e7717c4955e5a81c.jpg",
  "https://images.oyoroomscdn.com/uploads/hotel_image/1097/09938b4f62ca370e.jpg",
  "https://images.oyoroomscdn.com/uploads/hotel_image/1097/697ac4b4514d9d5c.jpg",
  "https://images.oyoroomscdn.com/uploads/hotel_image/1097/e0306175706fe9ce.jpg",
  "https://images.oyoroomscdn.com/uploads/hotel_image/1097/6d09a807ebb7860b.jpg",
  "https://images.oyoroomscdn.com/uploads/hotel_image/1097/10bd1eba8dfe318b.jpg",
  "https://images.oyoroomscdn.com/uploads/hotel_image/1097/cff9e8bd0c7e5ec7.jpg",
  "https://images.oyoroomscdn.com/uploads/hotel_image/1097/722e852d720c3d25.jpg",
  "https://images.oyoroomscdn.com/uploads/hotel_image/1097/dc3e2c5631c8ab48.jpg",
  "https://images.oyoroomscdn.com/uploads/hotel_image/1097/9c0ac971e3a244e0.jpg",
  "https://images.oyoroomscdn.com/uploads/hotel_image/1097/616b292e99049410.jpg",
  "https://images.oyoroomscdn.com/uploads/hotel_image/1097/ae03a8b55273958a.jpg",
  "https://images.oyoroomscdn.com/uploads/hotel_image/1097/748114df7b1ecb21.jpg",
  "https://images.oyoroomscdn.com/uploads/hotel_image/1097/021358e328ecc9dd.jpg",
  "https://images.oyoroomscdn.com/uploads/hotel_image/1097/13174c9f54ada03f.jpg"
]"
```

Comment: dose this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43083605/angular-2-display-array-of-images/43084368 is your answer?

Comment: iterate through the array and use src as a dynamic property

Comment: Are you sure that `"` comma's are there?

Answer (score 1):

use `*ngFor` and `[src]` for render image in html view

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/how-to-render-array-of-images-in-html-view?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

```
<div  *ngFor="let image of images" >
  <img [src]='image'/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

.ts

```
images:[
"https://images.oyoroomscdn.com/uploads/hotel_image/1097/340ea5ee01acc37f.jpg",
"https://images.oyoroomscdn.com/uploads/hotel_image/1097/9b75ea873012234c.jpg"
]
```

.html

```
<div *ngFor="let img of images">
    <img [src]="img" />
</div>
```