# ngFor with ngIf

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="selectShop">
    <li *ngFor="let s of i.shops_id">
       <a *ngFor="let shop of shops">
             <span *ngIf="shop._id == s">{{ shop.name }}</span>
       </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

It's created empty `a` tags but I need

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="selectShop">
    <li *ngFor="let s of i.shops_id">
       <a *ngFor="let shop of shops" *ngIf="shop._id == s">
             {{ shop.name }}
       </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

This code throws an error.

> core.es5.js:1084 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template
>   parse errors: Can't have multiple template bindings on one element.
>   Use only one attribute named 'template' or prefixed with *
>   ("`lledby="selectShop">
>                   <li *ngFor="let s of i.shops_id"><a *ngFor="let shop of shops" [ERROR ->]*ngIf="shop._id == s">{{ shop.name }}</a></li>
>                 </ul>
>               </div>`"):

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Please include the error you are seeing in your question.  Also, check out [ask] for details on how to ask good questions.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34657821/ngif-and-ngfor-on-same-element-causing-error  this answer not resolve my problem

Comment: use `<ng-container>` instead of `<span>`

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/IPEOFZuIyg1iDZfazEqX?p=preview. Will it help?

Comment: Thanks <ng-container> fix this problem  @yurzui

Comment: Glad to hear! :)