# angular2 updating view after model change

Tags: angular, typescript

I am just getting started with Angular 2 after working with AngularJS for the last couple of years.

I have a Component which displays some info about the user and depending on which variable is declared, The markup will adjust according the value of `showStuff` variable. `stuff2` is the default. `stuff1` should display a repeated list of data. When the user clicks `showStuffOne()`, the variable does change to the correct value however the data that is subscribed in the function is not being updated to the view.

I'm a bit stumped on the correct "angular2" way to update a view when the model changes in this particular instance. I've seen multiple posts about DetectionChange, ngZone and behaviorSubject, but not really sure what direction would solve this. Consider the following:

**user-page.html**

```
<ion-row>       
    <ion-col>
        <button ion-button block (click)="showStuffOne()"> Stuff1 </button>
    </ion-col> 

    <ion-col>
        <button ion-button block> Store </button>
    </ion-col>

    <ion-col>
        <button ion-button block (click)="showStuffTwo()"> Stuff2 </button>
    </ion-col>   
</ion-row>


<ion-list *ngIf="showStuff == 'stuff1'" ngFor="let event of eventList" >
    <h3>{{event.title}}</h3>
    <span>{{event.location}}</span>
</ion-list>

<ion-list *ngIf="showStuff == 'stuff2'">stuff2</ion-list>
```

**user-page.ts:**

```
import { Component, NgZone, OnInit, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams, ModalController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseObjectObservable, FirebaseListObservable} from 'angularfire2/database';

import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';

@Component({
    templateUrl: 'user-page.html',
    selector: 'user-page'
})

export class UserPage {

    userId: string;
    eventList: string[];
    showStuff: string;


    constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef, private zone: NgZone, public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, private afDB: AngularFireDatabase, public modalCtrl: ModalController) {
        console.log(this.navParams.get('username'))
        var getUsr = afDB.list('https://myendpoint.com/users', {
            query: {
                orderByChild: 'uname',
                equalTo: this.navParams.get('username')
            }

        }).subscribe(data => {
            console.log(data)
            this.userId = data[0].uid;

        })

    }


    ngOnInit() {
        this.showStuff = 'stuff2';
    }


    showStuffOne() {
        console.log("stuff1")
        this.userEvents(this.userId);


    }
    showStuffTwo() {
        console.log("stuff2")
        this.showStuff = 'stuff2';

    }

    openEvent = function(key) {
        console.log(key)
        let eventObj = {
            eventKey: key
        }
        let eventModal = this.modalCtrl.create(EventModal, eventObj);
        eventModal.present()
    };

    userEvents(userid: string) {
        var getUsrEvnts = this.afDB.list("http://myendpoint.com/event", {
            query: {
                orderByChild: "created_by",
                equalTo: userid
            }
        }).subscribe(data => {

            this.showStuff = 'stuff1'; // this correctly updates the variable, changing the view
            this.eventList = data; // data not updating, returning undefined, however the data logs here
            console.log(this.eventList)

        })
    }

}
```

**EDIT:** 
answer can be found at 
[this posting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39565934/2141706%0A)

Comment: Two ideas to try: set this.eventList=data before setting this.showStuff='stuff1';.... You might also try appending the data items to this.eventList rather than setting the variable equal to data. Good luck!

Comment: Also, should you be using *ngFor rather than ngFor?

Comment: @rafe tried both recommendations. Same errors. Reason why I'm using ngFor (non asterisk) is because i have the *ngIf. If I add *ngFor the showView doesn't seems to even trigger.

Comment: If you could replicate this in a plnkr its very easy to debug. Code looks fine

Comment: try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34657821/ngif-and-ngfor-on-same-element-causing-error

Comment: @avi  wow, that did it.  Thanks a lot. Found some useful info here as well https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives. A bit buried in the documentation though.