# Not showing li in ngFor statement

Tags: angular

I am trying to write a pager.

I would like to not put the `<li>` element to the dom if `number=-1`.

I could not write `ngIf` inside an `ngFor` so if anyone could show me the way I would appreciate it.

Here is what I'd like to improve:

```html
<li *ngFor="let number of pagerArray" class="page-item">
  <a class="page-link" href="#">{{number}}</a>
</li>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [\*ngIf and \*ngFor on same element causing error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34657821/ngif-and-ngfor-on-same-element-causing-error)

Comment: @DavidG. I don't think that this question is a duplicate because the problem is not the same, the quesiton you linked is a problem with ngFor inside ngIf, here it's the opposite: ngIf inside ngFor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the ng-container:

> is a logical container that can be used to group nodes
>   but is not rendered in the DOM tree as a node.

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let number of pagerArray">
    <li *ngIf="number != -1"  class="page-item">
        <a class="page-link" href="#">{{number}}</a>
    </li>
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) for that:

In your component:

```
getPagerArray(){
    return this.pagerArray.filter((num) => {
        return num >= 0;
    });
}
```

in your template:

```
<li *ngFor="let number of getPagerArray()" class="page-item">
    <a class="page-link" href="#">{{number}}</a>
</li>
```

Comment: It will be executing the filter function in every change detection cycle, not much safe for performance solution.

Comment: It would be the same for a pipe or a ngIf (ngIf wont use filter but it'll still check the condition). So I don't think that the performance loss is that fat, but I agree, the best solution would involve modfying the change detection strategy for an `OnPush` one to reduce the filter calls.

Answer (score 1):

there is many ways you can implemented with. 
one way you can set the *ngIf on the a tag

```
<li *ngFor="let number of pagerArray" class="page-item">
    <a class="page-link" href="#" *ngIf='number != -1'>
        {{number}}
    </a>
</li>
```

another way you can do it is by adding your own filter as follow

```
<li *ngFor="let number of pagerArray | yourFilter" class="page-item">
    <a class="page-link" href="#">
        {{number}}
    </a>
</li>
```

Comment: The first instruction will add empty `<li></li>` elements to DOM.