# Angular 4 - show/Hide elements on ngFor directive

Tags: angular, list, show

I have a list of lists and I want to hide/show internal list based on an attribute value

```
<md-list *ngFor="let el of data">
    <md-list-item *ngFor="let item of el.items" >
      <h4 mdSubhead]er>{{item.name}}</h4>
    </md-list-item>h4
  </md-list>
```

I have tried with `*ngIf`, but Angular4 permit only one template binding for an element.

How can I implement this beavior?

Comment: what is the show / hide condition? You may use an `ng-container` or try with the `[hidden]` attribute.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [\*ngIf and \*ngFor on same element causing error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34657821/ngif-and-ngfor-on-same-element-causing-error)

Answer (score 3):

You can just do by adding a extra `div` with a condition or **`ng-container`** which would be the best for angular

```
<md-list *ngFor="let el of data">
  <ng-container *ngIf="el.something">
    <md-list-item *ngFor="let item of el.items" >
      <h4 mdSubheader>{{item.name}}</h4>
    </md-list-item>
  </ng-container>
 </md-list>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`ng-container`](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#ngcontainer) (no need of extra element) and on the same use `*ngIf` to `hide/show` DOM conditionally.

```
<md-list *ngFor="let el of data">
  <ng-container *ngIf="el.show">
    <md-list-item *ngFor="let item of el.items" >
      <h4 mdSubhead]er>{{item.name}}</h4>
    </md-list-item>
  </ng-container>
</md-list>
```

Comment: Cleverest solution since `ng-container` won't be added to the DOM. This is the correct approach.

Comment: ng-container > ng-template > DOM element for cases like this

Answer (score 1):

I think best way might be to get data before, then remove unneeded items and iterate through remaining lists. But if really need in template, so you can use ng-template and long *ngFor version, so something like:

```
<ng-template ngFor let-el [ngForOf]="data" let-i="index">
 <md-list #el>
 <ng-template ngFor let-item [ngForOf]="el.items" let-i="index">
  <md-list-item #item>
    </md-list-item>h4
  </ng-template>
 </md-list>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: Just to add to John Snow you can add a filter to filter out what you don't want.

Answer (score 0):

Use `<ng-container>` as mentioned here : [`<ng-container>` to the rescue](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#ng-container-to-the-rescue)

```
<md-list *ngFor="let el of data">
    <ng-container *ngIf="your-condition-here">
        <md-list-item *ngFor="let item of el.items" >
            <h4 mdSubhead]er>{{item.name}}</h4>
        </md-list-item>
    </ng-container>
</md-list>
```