# *ngIf and *ngFor on same element

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have a problem when I use `*ngFor` and `*ngIf` on the same element.

```
  <div
    *ngFor="let recipeStep of RecipeSteps; let i = index"
    *ngIf="position === i">
    {{ recipeStep }}
  </div>

  <button ion-button small (click)="previous()">Previous</button>
  <button ion-button small (click)="next()">Next</button>
```

> I know the easy solution is to move the `*ngIf` on a new element.
>   **For Example:**

```
<ng-container *ngIf="position === i">
 <div *ngFor="let recipeStep of RecipeSteps; let i = index">
  {{ recipeStep }}
 </div>
<ng-container>
```

but when I use this solution I can't use `i` variable. and this solution hide all element on `<ng-container>`

So, this buttons is not useful now

```
<button ion-button small (click)="previous()">Previous</button>
<button ion-button small (click)="next()">Next</button>
```

this typescript fill

```
position: number;
ionViewDidLoad() {
  this.position = 1; 
}

next() {
  this.position = this.position + 1;
}
previous() {
  this.position = this.position - 1;
}
```

**My question is** Are there different way use `*ngFor` and `*ngIf` on the same element.

**If there are no way** are there different way to be this buttons useful

Comment: You can put the `ngFor` directive on the `ng-container` and the `ngIf` directive on the `div`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to put the ngIf and the ngFor the other way around:

```
 <div *ngFor="let recipeStep of RecipeSteps; let i = index">
  <ng-container *ngIf="position === i">{{ recipeStep }}</ng-container>
 </div>
```

Comment: This would produce an empty div for the "hidden" element. If the div has some styling (e.g. padding + border + margin), you will see it. You could keep the `ng-container` outside and swap only the directives, in order to remove the div completely.

Answer (score 2):

As you can see in this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34657821/ngif-and-ngfor-on-same-element-causing-error) Angular does not support more than one structural directive on one element.

You need to use your `*ngIf` inside the `*ngFor`:

```
<div *ngFor="let recipeStep of RecipeSteps; let i = index">
  <div *ngIf="position === i">
   {{ recipeStep }}
  </div>
</div>
```