# How to set a class only to specific elements when using *ngFor?

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript, angular5

I am using `*ngFor` to list table data: `*ngFor="let record of records"`,
and I want to set custom css class to `record` based on some conditions, f.e. `if record.name === something`. Is this possible?

Comment: `[ngClass]="record.name === 'something' ? 'yourClass' : 'otherClass' "`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34657821/ngif-and-ngfor-on-same-element-causing-error Can you refer here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this way :

```
  <ul class="r " *ngFor="let posto of posti">
    <li [ngClass]="posto.id === something ? NewClass : oldclass" >
     {{Something.id}} 
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you on `[ngClass]` to achieve this, for example:

```
<div [ngClass]="{'record': record.name === 'something' }" *ngFor="let record of records">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<tr *ngFor="let record of records">    
  <td [ngClass]="record.name === 'something' ? 'classForSomething' : 'classForOthers' ">{{record.name}}</td> 
</tr>
```