# Ordering of custom item in *ngFor directive

Tags: angular, ngfor

This is my code:

```
    <nav>
        <a [routerLink]="item.link"
            *ngFor="let item of links; let lastItem = last;"  
            *ngIf="!lastItem">
            {{item.title}}
        </a>
        <a (click)="clickOnCustomLink()">
            MY CUSTOM LINK
        </a>
        <a *ngIf="links" [routerLink]="links[links.length - 1].link">
            {{links[links.length - 1].title}}
        </a>
    </nav>
```

For known reasons I get an error:

`Can't have multiple template bindings on one element`

Any ideas?

Comment: Duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34657821/ngif-and-ngfor-on-same-element-causing-error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can't use more than one structural directive on one angular element

Instead use [ng-container](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#ng-container-to-the-rescue) for running the for loop (ng-containers are not rendered in your DOM) :

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of links; let lastItem = last;"  >
    <a [routerLink]="item.link" *ngIf="!lastItem">
        {{item.title}}
    </a>
<ng-container>
```

Comment: You just need to swap the directives ;)

Answer (score 2):

cant add two structural directives on one element. Create a new `ng-container` and move the `ngFor` into that one

```
   <ng-container [routerLink]="item.link" *ngFor="let item of links; let lastItem = last;" >
        <a [routerLink]="item.link" *ngIf="!lastItem">
               {{item.title}}
         </a> 
    </ng-container>
```