# Conditionally render a LI item in a For loop

Tags: angular, angular7

I have the following using Angular 7:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let status of statuses$ | async" *ngIf="status.name != post.statusName">
    {{status.name}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

I get the following error:

```
Can't have multiple template bindings on one element. Use only one attribute prefixed with *
```

How can I conditionally render a LI item in a loop?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34657821/ngif-and-ngfor-on-same-element-causing-error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only one structural directive on an element to Change your code to

```
<ul>
<ng-container *ngFor="let status of statuses$ | async">
 <li  *ngIf="status.name != post.statusName">
    {{status.name}}
  </li>
</ng-container>

</ul>
```

[Working stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-w9cbpo)

Comment: Yes ng-container is best for this

Answer (score 2):

separate the `ngIf` and `ngFor`. You can't have 2 structured directives on one element

```
<ul>
  <ng-template  *ngFor="let status of statuses$ | async" > 
    <li *ngIf="status.name != post.statusName">
     {{status.name}}
     </li>
  </ng-template>
</ul>
```

Comment: `ng-template` will not display any item https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-evccfd

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
 <ul>
 <li *ngFor="let status of statuses$ | async" >
 <div *ngIf="status.name != post.statusName">
  <p>{{status.name}}</p>
 </div>
 </li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: it will create extra `div` with each itration

Answer (score 0):

We Can't use ngif and ngfor together

```
        <ul>
          <li *ngFor="let status of statuses$ | async" >
            <div *ngIf="status.name != post.statusName">
              <span>{{status.name}}</span>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
```

Comment: it will create blank li item if condition doesn't match