# Stuck on trying to understand how Promises in JS worked

Tags: javascript, angular, promise

I'm developing mobile application, using Ionic 4 & Angular 8.
And I have some troubles, trying to achieve simple tasks.

So, I'm using: 
[@ionic-native/native-storage](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/native-storage) & [@angular/http](https://angular.io/guide/http) in Angular service like this:

```
async getToken() {
    await this.storage.getItem('token')
        .then((res) => {
            this.token = res
        })
}
```

This is an Promise resolving function, am I right?

Then, I need to call this async/await function in another function:

```
latest() {
    this.getToken()

    let options = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
            'Auth-Key': this.token
        })
    }

    return this.http.get(this.env.API_URL + 'url', options)
}
```

Next step is call service function from the page:

```
getLatestVideo() {
    this.videoService.latest()
        .subscribe(data => {
            this.latestVideo = data;
        })
}
```

**And now the problem:**

The function getting 'token' from storage, did not finished, and Promise did not resolved, when I'm trying to get this token.

So, when I call HttpClient, and trying to get some data from api, I get an error, that says: 'token, you trying to call is null'.

Can someone explain how is Promises works? I can't get it

**UPDATE 1:**

Problem is resolved by 2 steps:
Step 1: 
Make latest() async

```
async latest() {
    await this.getToken()

    let options = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
            'Auth-Key': this.token
        })
    }

    return this.http.get(this.env.API_URL + 'url', options)
}
```

Step 2:
Make getLatestVideo() async too

```
async getLatestVideo() {
    const latestVideo = await this.videoService.latest();

    latestVideo.subscribe(data => {
        this.latestVideo = data;
    })
}
```

---

**New problem:** How to display data after all promises resolved inside view:

```
<div *ngFor="let video of latestVideo">{{ video.id }}</div>
```

Comment: Just use "await this.getToken()" and it will wait for the promise to finish.

Comment: @AlexanderElert Im getting an error in getLatestVideo(), says that .subscribe does not exists on type Promise, when I'm use wait this.getToken()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
getToken(): Observable<string> {
    return from(this.storage.getItem('token'));
}

latest() {
  return this.getToken().pipe(
    switchMap(token => {
        const headers = new HttpHeaders({ auth: token });
        return this.http.get(this.env.API_URL + 'video', { headers });
    }),
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, you have to use some more awaits.

```
async latest() {
  await this.getToken()

  let options = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
          'Auth-Key': this.token
      })
  }
  return this.http.get(this.env.API_URL + 'url', options)
}
```

Next step

```
async getLatestVideo() {
  const latestVideo = await this.videoService.latest();
  latestVideo.subscribe(data => {
          this.latestVideo = data;
      })
}
```

Maybe this will help?

Comment: No. If `latest()` doesn't await `this.getToken()`, then it'll make the second HTTP call immediately, before token is retrieved.

Comment: I have added async await to latest(), I get token, I get info from server. But the problem is now, that I cant display it in .html with *ngFor

Comment: Ah, didn't know that get token is also async. But in the Angular question i can't help, sorry :) Could you just wrap a if araound the ngFor and wait, til the data is complete?

Comment: May this be helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34657821/ngif-and-ngfor-on-same-element-causing-error

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making all of your functions async-await, you can return promises. Eg

`getToken() {
    return this.storage.getItem('token')
}`

Then in latest you can simply have:

```
const token = await this.getToken()
let options = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Auth-Key': token 
    })
}

return this.http.get(this.env.API_URL + 'url', options)
```